# Ternary operator in AngularJS templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ternary-operator

How do you do a ternary with AngularJS (in the templates)?

It would be nice to use some in html attributes (classes and style) instead of creating and calling a function of the controller.

Answer (score 373, accepted):

**Update**: Angular 1.1.5 added a [ternary operator](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b), so now we can simply write

```
<li ng-class="$first ? 'firstRow' : 'nonFirstRow'">
```

---

If you are using an earlier version of Angular, your two choices are:

1. `(condition && result_if_true || !condition && result_if_false)`
2. `{true: 'result_if_true', false: 'result_if_false'}[condition]`

item 2. above creates an object with two properties.  The array syntax is used to select either the property with name true or the property with name false, and return the associated value.

E.g.,

```
<li class="{{{true: 'myClass1 myClass2', false: ''}[$first]}}">...</li>
 or
<li ng-class="{true: 'myClass1 myClass2', false: ''}[$first]">...</li>
```

$first is set to true inside an ng-repeat for the first element, so the above would apply class 'myClass1' and 'myClass2' only the first time through the loop.

With **ng-class** there is an easier way though:  ng-class takes an expression that must evaluate to one of the following:

1. a string of space-delimited class names
2. an array of class names
3. a map/object of class names to boolean values.

An example of 1) was given above.  Here is an example of 3, which I think reads much better:

```
 <li ng-class="{myClass: $first, anotherClass: $index == 2}">...</li>
```

The first time through an ng-repeat loop, class myClass is added.  The 3rd time through ($index starts at 0), class anotherClass is added.

**ng-style** takes an expression that must evaluate to a map/object of CSS style names to CSS values.  E.g.,

```
 <li ng-style="{true: {color: 'red'}, false: {}}[$first]">...</li>
```

Comment: If I could I would upvote you again for updating the question!

Comment: I'll take care of it, @Narretz.

Comment: In the object-key accessing example, you can skip the 'false' key as it's anyways empty string.

Comment: Word of warning, 1.1.5 is not currently stable.

Comment: What if the conditional changes when your model is updated? I'd like the `ng-style` to update, but it seems to only be evaluated when the element is first rendered. (Angular noob here)

Comment: @HartleyBrody, you are probably changing your model "outside" of Angular, so you'll need to call $apply() to cause Angular to re-evaluate the ng-style expression.

Comment: A bit too late, but does anyone know a sort of linter which can be used for such templates to disallow those things? (e.g. set complexity to 1 or 2 or sort of)

Comment: Does this only work for class? What about ui-sref for example?

Answer (score 86):

**Update:** Angular 1.1.5 added a ternary operator, this answer is correct only to versions preceding 1.1.5. For 1.1.5 and later, see the currently accepted answer.

**Before  Angular 1.1.5:**

The form of a ternary in angularjs is:

```
((condition) && (answer if true) || (answer if false))
```

An example would be:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a   href="#/page1" style="{{$location.path()=='/page2' && 'color:#fff;' || 'color:#000;'}}">Goals</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a   href="#/page2" style="{{$location.path()=='/page2' && 'color:#fff;' || 'color:#000;'}}">Groups</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or:

```
 <li  ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=0"  class="{{(currentPage == 0) && 'disabled' || ''}}"><a> << </a></li>
```

Comment: Weird. That's not very intuitive. I wonder why it was implemented this way.

Comment: Ternary was never implemneted, but this is just using the binary operators the way they work.

Comment: @blesh, AngularJS promotes testability. Templates should not contain any logic. A ternary operator in a template should be refactored to a function call to the controller, for better testability.

Comment: Should the above examples be using ng-style and ng-class?  (I'm not sure when they need to be used).

Comment: @Mark, if you want to use ng-style, then the expression needs to eval to an object whose keys are CSS style names and whose values are the CSS values.  E.g., ng-style="{color: $location.path()=='/page2' && '#fff' || '#000'}".  I think this reads a bit nicer, since it is easier to tell you are setting 'color'.

Comment: @MarcelloNuccio can you elaborate on that? I want to print css clases according to a boolean property, how would I refactor that to the controller exactly? (i'm a noob, i know)

Comment: @arg20 you should use [ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass) directive (or ngClassEven and ngClassOdd). Then put all the logic for choosing css classes in the controller. This is much more easy to test automatically.

Comment: @MarcelloNuccio but is it a good idea to put classes names on the model? They belong in the view, the model shouldn't be aware of what css classes the view uses. What would be best is if I could use a boolean property from the model, like `ng-class="someboolean: 'myCssClass'"`

Comment: @arg20 I said to put it in the controller, not in the model. This should not be a problem. However, the documentation says: "The result of the evaluation can be a string representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class names to boolean values". Meaning that you can use "{ cssclass: someBoolCheck() }" as an expression, i.e. you put the css class in the view, and the logic in the controller. Look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MnJX2/) for an example.

Answer (score 22):

For texts in angular template (`userType` is property of $scope, like $scope.userType):

```
<span>
  {{userType=='admin' ? 'Edit' : 'Show'}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 10):

This answer predates version [1.1.5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#115-triangle-squarification-2013-05-22) where a proper ternary in the `$parse` function wasn't available. Use this answer if you're on a lower version, or as an example of filters:

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', [])
  
  .filter('conditional', function() {
    return function(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse) {
      return condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse;
    };
  });
```

And then use it as

```
<i ng-class="checked | conditional:'icon-check':'icon-check-empty'"></i>
```

Comment: I came to this question for the ternary operator but at the end I went with a filter and it felt really good... =D

Answer (score 10):

While you can use the `condition && if-true-part || if-false-part`-syntax in older versions of angular, the usual ternary operator `condition ? true-part : false-part` is available in [Angular 1.1.5 and later](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#115-triangle-squarification-2013-05-22).

Answer (score 10):

There it is : ternary operator got added to angular parser in **1.1.5**! [see the changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lionroots/JRdRp/) showing new ternary operator used in ng-class directive.

```
ng-class="boolForTernary ? 'blue' : 'red'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <body ng-app="app">
  <button type="button" ng-click="showme==true ? !showme :showme;message='Cancel Quiz'"  class="btn btn-default">{{showme==true ? 'Cancel Quiz': 'Take a Quiz'}}</button>
    <div ng-show="showme" class="panel panel-primary col-sm-4" style="margin-left:250px;">
      <div class="panel-heading">Take Quiz</div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-8 form-inline" style="margin-top: 30px;margin-bottom: 30px;">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Start Quiz</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Button toggle and change header of button and show/hide div panel. See the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yj0kxW?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is still working on legacy code like I'm you can also achieve this using a ternary operator inside ng-style like so:

```
<li ng-style="{'color': connected ? '#008000' : '#808080'}"></li>
```