# angularjs: ng-src equivalent for background-image:url(...)

Tags: css, angularjs

In angularjs you have the [tag ng-src](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc) which has the purpose that you won't receive an error for an invalid url before angularjs gets to evaluate the variables placed in between `{{` and `}}`.

The problem is that I use quite some DIV's with a `background-image` set to an url. I do this because of the excellent CSS3 property `background-size` which crops the image to the exact size of the DIV.

The only problem is that I receive a lot of errors for the exact same reason they created a ng-src tag: I have some variables in the url and the browser thinks the image doesn't exist.

I realize that there is a possibility of writing a crude `{{"style='background-image:url(myVariableUrl)'"}}`, but this seems 'dirty'.

I've searched a lot and can't find the right way to do this. My app is becoming a mess because of all of these errors.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

`ngSrc` is a native directive, so it seems you want a similar directive that modifies your div's  `background-image` style.

You could write your own directive that does exactly what you want. For example

```
app.directive('backImg', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        var url = attrs.backImg;
        element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + url +')',
            'background-size' : 'cover'
        });
    };
});​
```

Which you would invoke like this

```
<div back-img="<some-image-url>" ></div>
```

JSFiddle with cute cats as a bonus: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/aSjwk/1/

Comment: Very nice directive; the only problem is that it doesn't support interpolation. I would probably modify it thusly: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/aSjwk/2/

Comment: Thank you, it doesn´t matter that is is without interpolation, it has kittens!

Comment: Any security issues with this if you are loading from untrusted sources?

Comment: this works, but only if your image url is already defined, use @mythz answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15537359/1479680 to have a better obeservable url

Answer (score 232):

This one works for me

```
<li ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/static/'+imgURL+')'}">...</li>
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. There's no need to add a custom directive.

Comment: I added an answer similar to that one, just using interpolation

Comment: It's dirtier, in the sense that a directive fits all, everywhere you need a dynamic background. The question mentioned it felt less reusable.

Comment: Doesn't work in Angular 1.5.8, it still tries to load the image with `imgURL` not set and retries when `imgURL` gets set.

Comment: This is incorrect, if you have any special variables like @% in your URL, it will break.

Comment: @efwjames this answer provides the right idea; you're encountering a separate problem involving how the browser parses the `url` css declaration. You should quote its contents: `ng-style="{'background-image':'url(\'/static/'+imgURL+'\')'}"` although considering all the levels of quoting it becomes messy

Answer (score 69):

The above answer doesn't support observable interpolation (and cost me a lot of time trying to debug). The [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/aSjwk/2/) in @BrandonTilley comment was the answer that worked for me, which I'll re-post here for preservation:

```
app.directive('backImg', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        attrs.$observe('backImg', function(value) {
            element.css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + value +')',
                'background-size' : 'cover'
            });
        });
    };
});
```

---

Example using controller and template

***Controller :***

```
$scope.someID = ...;
/* 
The advantage of using directive will also work inside an ng-repeat :
someID can be inside an array of ID's 
*/

$scope.arrayOfIDs = [0,1,2,3];
```

***Template :***

Use in template like so :

```
<div back-img="img/service-sliders/{{someID}}/1.jpg"></div>
```

or like so :

```
<div ng-repeat="someID in arrayOfIDs" back-img="img/service-sliders/{{someID}}/1.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 40):

It's also possible to do something like this with `ng-style`:

```
ng-style="image_path != '' && {'background-image':'url('+image_path+')'}"
```

which would not attempt to fetch a non-existing image.

Comment: @sqren also see this if you are using a newer version of Angular (1.1.5 and above): http://stackoverflow.com/a/12151492/1218080 . Support for an actual ternary operator in views was added.

Comment: simple string concatenation like this worked for me on scope object, instead of interpolation.

Answer (score 25):

Similar to hooblei's answer, just with interpolation:

```
<li ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{ image.source }})'}">...</li>
```

Comment: It didn't work here: `<span ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(/styles/images/profile.png)'}" style="background-image: url("");"></span>`. @hooblei approach worked.

Comment: Getting same result :(

Answer (score 9):

just a matter of taste but if you prefer accessing the variable or function directly like this:

```
<div id="playlist-icon" back-img="playlist.icon">
```

instead of interpolating like this:

```
<div id="playlist-icon" back-img="{{playlist.icon}}">
```

then you can define the directive a bit differently with `scope.$watch` which will do `$parse` on the
attribute

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('bgImage', function(){

    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.bgImage, function(value) {
            element.css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + value +')',
                'background-size' : 'cover'
            });
        });
    };
})
```

there is more background on this here: [AngularJS : Difference between the $observe and $watch methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-the-observe-and-watch-methods)

Answer (score 2):

@jaime your answer is fine. But if your page has the $http.get then you have use ng-if

```
app.directive('backImg', function(){
    return function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        var url = $attrs.backImg;
        $element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + url + ')',
            'background-size': 'cover'
        });
    }
});
```

in the factory

```
app.factory('dataFactory', function($http){
    var factory = {};
    factory.getAboutData = function(){
        return $http.get("api/about-data.json");
    };
    return factory;
});
```

in the controller area

```
app.controller('aboutCtrl', function($scope, $http, dataFactory){
    $scope.aboutData = [];
    dataFactory.getAboutData().then(function(response){
        // get full home data
        $scope.aboutData = response.data;
        // banner data
        $scope.banner = {
            "image": $scope.aboutData.bannerImage,
            "text": $scope.aboutData.bannerText
        };
    });
});
```

and the view if you use the ng-if like below then you will get the image by interpolation otherwise, you can't get the image because directive get the value before HTTP request.

```
<div class="stat-banner"  ng-if="banner.image" background-image-directive="{{banner.image}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found with 1.5 components that abstracting the styling from the DOM to work best in my async situation.

Example:

```
<div ng-style="{ 'background': $ctrl.backgroundUrl }"></div>
```

And in the controller, something likes this:

```
this.$onChanges = onChanges;

function onChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.value.currentValue){
        $ctrl.backgroundUrl = setBackgroundUrl(changes.value.currentValue);
    }
}

function setBackgroundUrl(value){
    return 'url(' + value.imgUrl + ')';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned `ng-src` and it seems as though you want the page to finish rendering before loading your image, you may modify jaime's answer to run the native directive *after* the browser finishes rendering.

[This blog post](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering) explains this pretty well; essentially, you insert the [`$timeout` wrapper](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) for `window.setTimeout` before the callback function wherein you make those modifications to the CSS.