# Conditionally change img src based on model data

Tags: angularjs

I want to represent model data as different images using Angular but having some trouble finding the "right" way to do it.  The Angular [API docs on expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) say that conditional expressions are not allowed...

Simplifying a lot, the model data is fetched via AJAX and shows you the status of each interface on a router.  Something like:

```
$scope.interfaces = ["UP", "DOWN", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "DOWN"]
```

So, in Angular, we can display the state of each interface with something like:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat=interface in interfaces>{{interface}}
</ul>
```

BUT - Instead of the values from the model, I'd like to show a suitable image.  Something following this general idea.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat=interface in interfaces>
    {{if interface=="UP"}}
       <img src='green-checkmark.png'>
    {{else}}
       <img src='big-black-X.png'>
    {{/if}}
</ul>
```

*(I think Ember supports this type of construct)*

Of course, I could modify the controller to return image URLs based on the actual model data but that seems to violate the separation of model and view, no?

[This SO Posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781685/angularjs-ng-src-equivalent-for-background-imageurl/13782311#13782311) suggested using a directive to change the bg-img source.  But then we are back to putting URLs in the JS not the template...

All suggestions appreciated.  Thanks.

*please excuse any typos*

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Instead of `src` you need `ng-src`.

AngularJS views support binary operators

```
condition && true || false
```

So your `img` tag would look like this

```
<img ng-src="{{interface == 'UP' && 'green-checkmark.png' || 'big-black-X.png'}}"/>
```

**Note** : the quotes (ie 'green-checkmark.png') are important here. It won't work without quotes.

[plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vwNAE3tQxE6VzO0TLDsk?p=preview) *(open dev tools to see the produced HTML)*

Comment: Thanks! I looked in the docs for exactly that but they're pretty sparse on expressions.

Comment: This is a lifesaver; The docs don't really mention that you can use binary operators in ng-src

Comment: In the latest unstable Angular (I am on 1.1.4) you can use ng-attr- to set any attribute the same way.

Comment: can we add multiple condition to ng-src?

Comment: @Sutirth: yes, by using a function: `<img ng-src="{{myfunction(interface)}}"/>` and return the answer based on multiple conditions in that function in the controller.

Comment: Can we get an angular v4 version of this?

Comment: @LoveenDyall there's now an answer that works for newer versions of Angular, by Sachin at the bottom of the answers

Answer (score 34):

Another alternative (other than binary operators suggested by @jm-) is to use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch):

```
<span ng-switch on="interface">
   <img ng-switch-when="UP" src='green-checkmark.png'>
   <img ng-switch-default   src='big-black-X.png'>
</span>
```

ng-switch will likely be better/easier if you have more than two images.

Answer (score 23):

Another way ..

```
<img ng-src="{{!video.playing ? 'img/icons/play-rounded-button-outline.svg' : 'img/icons/pause-thin-rounded-button.svg'}}" />
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat=interface in interfaces>
       <img src='green-checkmark.png' ng-show="interface=='UP'" />
       <img src='big-black-X.png' ng-show="interface=='DOWN'" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this with it shows the two images for a tiny fraction of time.

Comment: @Sebastialonso perhaps try ng-if instead?

Answer (score 4):

For angular 4 I have used

```
<img [src]="data.pic ? data.pic : 'assets/images/no-image.png' " alt="Image" title="Image">
```

It works for me , I hope it may use to other's also for `Angular 4-5`. :)