# How to prevent ng-src to load image before data arrives?

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
 <img ng-src="{{plugins.filesPath.album_images.image}}{{album.cover_image}}" alt="{{album.title}}" />
```

While running the app, it shows error:

```
GET http://url.com/myApp/files/album_images/image/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

"http://url.com/myApp/files/album_images/image/" is the value of {{plugins.filesPath.album_images.image}}.

It shows error because it goes to load the image before all data arrives..

How can i prevent this error in console?

Answer (score 32):

Try to use the conditional pattern `condition && true || false`

Therefore modify `ng-src` attribute like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{ album && plugins.filesPath.album_images.image + album.cover_image || '' }}" alt="{{album.title}}" />
```

With this change, the content of `src` attribute is empty until the data arrives.

*Source:* [Conditionally change img src based on model data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999659/conditionally-change-img-src-based-on-model-data/13999837#13999837)

Comment: These conditionals are very handy.  I did not know they existed.

Answer (score 11):

### Update March 2015

Using Angular 1.3.x should make most custom data checks obsolete, since [$interpolate now includes a flag "allOrNothing"](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/service/$interpolate) that will wait for ALL bindings to be something other than undefined, before actually resolving the expression.

So in this case, `ng-src` will only insert the `src` attribute once both `album_images.image` **and** `album.cover_image` are ready. Still, depending on your setup, `album.title` might not be ready yet, so if you want to wait for that you could still use the `isDataAvailable()` approach.

### Original Answer:

Now that there's `ng-if`, one could try

`<img ng-if="isDataAvailable()" ng-src="{{plugins.filesPath.album_images.image}}{{album.cover_image}}" alt="{{album.title}}" />`

```
$scope.isDataAvailable = function(){
    // do your data checks here and
    // return true;
}
```

That way the image is only appended to the DOM as soon as `isDataAvailable` returns `true` and only then `ng-src` will kick in and try to get the file.

Still, I'm pretty sure, `403 (Forbidden)` is somewhat related to directory/file access restrictions on your server.

Answer (score 6):

I believe ng-src waits for it's  value to change to apply a src value to the element.
Did you try changing

`<img ng-src="{{plugins.filesPath.album_images.image}}{{album.cover_image}}"`

to

`<img ng-src="{{plugins.filesPath.album_images.image + album.cover_image}}"` ?

**EDIT** - *revised answer*

As ng-src waits for the information in {{}} to change, it has no way of knowing if EVERY aspect of it is ready. I can think of two possible solutions:

a) Make a `url_when_ready()` function, that takes strings as arguments and concatenates them, only returning a value if all of the strings are defined. Then do

`ng-src="{{url_when_ready([plugins.filesPath.album_images.image, album.cover_image])}}`

b) create a model $scope.album.cover_image_full that updates when $scope.album.cover_image is ready, and use that as the ng-src value

Answer (score 0):

like everyone else you can always show a loading sign before the image is completely loaded on the page. [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/XPGXh/1) containing the demo.
you can use a different image in background before loading using `.css('background-image','url('+ url_link_var +')');`

This is done and shown in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankcpdixit/XPGXh/1/).