# Preventing an image from loading until it is within the viewport using ng-src

Tags: angularjs

I would like to be able to prevent an image that has an ng-src attribute from loading until it is visible in the viewport.

Is this possible with Angular?

Previously I have used the [jQuery LazyLoad Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) , however I am trying to do this without having to have both Angular and jQuery.

Comment: Here there is a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433153/how-to-prevent-ng-src-to-load-image-before-data-arrives

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you're still interested, i found out this repo on github : 
https://github.com/afklm/ng-lazy-image

I tried it and it rocks !

Images are loaded only when appearing in viewport AND you can choose which image to load based on screen size. It means that you can load smaller images for mobile users ;)

Comment: I does not rock

Answer (score 5):

In angularjs, lazy loading can be implemented using a directive.

Steps:

Step 1. create directive as follows:

```
App.directive('lazyLoad', lazyLoad)
function lazyLoad() {
     return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                 const observer = new IntersectionObserver(loadImg);
                 const img = angular.element(element)[0];
                 observer.observe(img)
                 function loadImg(changes) {
                        changes.forEach(change => {
                              if (change.intersectionRatio > 0 && change.target.getAttribute('tempData')) {
                                    change.target.src = change.target.getAttribute('tempData');
                              }
                        });
                 }                     
          };
     };
};
```

Step 2: use lazy-load attribute in  tag and replace "ng-src" with tempData
eg. In html

```
<img ng-repeate="obj in objects" lazy-load tempData="obj.srcURL">
```

Note: we are not directly assigning src because we want to prevent image from sending request to server to load image.

Important Note: Dependence upon es-6. You may get parse error while making a build.

*Solution: npm install --save gulp-uglify-es

You need to update your gulp file after installing command.
This will install dependency and your code can make a build now.

That's all!!!

Thank you for reading!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just bind the source to a getter that only returns the value if the element is visible (assuming you are using a binding of some sort to trigger visibility of the img).

For example, use `ng-src="{{getImgSource()}}"` and in your controller:

```
scope.getImgSource = function(){
    if(scope.showImg){
        return "myImageUrl.png";
    }
    return ""; 
};
```

However, if that is something that you will have to use a lot, maybe you should look into creating your own directive to do that.

Comment: Turns out it was a bit more complicated...thanks for the answer though :-)