# Adding dynamic icon's to p-selectButton

Tags: angular, primeng

Has anyone found a way to dynamically attach icons to individual array elements on the SelectButton in primeng?
My scenario is to add appropriate icons according to status something like below picture.
 [image: Icons for tab]

Note: I am also looking at other similar frameworks like ng-bootstrap in case if this use-case can be easily implemented.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Use `ngIf` directive?

Comment: ng-src is the way to go , you can also use a condition inside angular expression check documents for more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc also a previous answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999659/conditionally-change-img-src-based-on-model-data

Comment: You can't set icon on a `selectButton`. Do you mean `splitButton` ?

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to mention primeng. I am using primeng components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the Primeng team accepted my enhancement [request](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4924) and implemented this feature [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/d081a74b7eaadbc0249fc1c96fab7fb9b2908f5d)