# AngularJS : Difference between the $observe and $watch methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that both `Watchers` and `Observers` are computed as soon as something in `$scope` changes in AngularJS. But couldn't understand what exactly is the difference between the two.

My initial understanding is that `Observers` are computed for angular expressions which are conditions on the HTML side where as `Watchers` executed when `$scope.$watch()` function is executed. Am I thinking properly?

Answer (score 613, accepted):

**[$observe()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe)** is a method on the [Attributes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile.directive.Attributes) object, and as such, it can only be used to observe/watch the value change of a DOM attribute.  It is only used/called inside directives.  Use $observe when you need to observe/watch a DOM attribute that contains interpolation (i.e., {{}}'s). 

E.g., `attr1="Name: {{name}}"`, then in a directive: `attrs.$observe('attr1', ...)`. 

(If you try `scope.$watch(attrs.attr1, ...)` it won't work because of the {{}}s -- you'll get `undefined`.)  Use $watch for everything else.

**[$watch()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch)** is more complicated.  It can observe/watch an "expression", where the expression can be either a function or a string.  If the expression is a string, it is [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse)'d (i.e., evaluated as an [Angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)) into a function.  (It is this function that is called every digest cycle.)  The string expression can not contain {{}}'s.  $watch is a method on the [Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope) object, so it can be used/called wherever you have access to a scope object, hence in

- a controller -- any controller -- one created via ng-view, ng-controller, or a directive controller
- a linking function in a directive, since this has access to a scope as well

Because strings are evaluated as Angular expressions, $watch is often used when you want to observe/watch a model/scope property.  E.g., `attr1="myModel.some_prop"`, then in a controller or link function: `scope.$watch('myModel.some_prop', ...)` or `scope.$watch(attrs.attr1, ...)` (or `scope.$watch(attrs['attr1'], ...)`).

(If you try `attrs.$observe('attr1')` you'll get the string `myModel.some_prop`, which is probably not what you want.)

As discussed in comments on @PrimosK's answer, all $observes and $watches are checked every [digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts).

Directives with isolate scopes are more complicated.  If the '@' syntax is used, you can $observe *or $watch* a DOM attribute that contains interpolation (i.e., {{}}'s).  (The reason it works with $watch is because the '@' syntax does the [interpolation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolate) for us, hence $watch sees a string without {{}}'s.)  To make it easier to remember which to use when, I suggest using $observe for this case also.

To help test all of this, I wrote a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HBha8sVdeCqhJtQghGxw?p=preview) that defines two directives.  One (`d1`) does not create a new scope, the other (`d2`) creates an isolate scope.  Each directive has the same six attributes.  Each attribute is both $observe'd and $watch'ed.

```
<div d1 attr1="{{prop1}}-test" attr2="prop2" attr3="33" attr4="'a_string'"
        attr5="a_string" attr6="{{1+aNumber}}"></div>
```

Look at the console log to see the differences between $observe and $watch in the linking function.  Then click the link and see which $observes and $watches are triggered by the property changes made by the click handler.

Notice that when the link function runs, any attributes that contain {{}}'s are not evaluated yet (so if you try to examine the attributes, you'll get `undefined`).  The only way to see the interpolated values is to use $observe (or $watch if using an isolate scope with '@').  Therefore, getting the values of these attributes is an *asynchronous* operation.  (And this is why we need the $observe and $watch functions.)

Sometimes you don't need $observe or $watch.  E.g., if your attribute contains a number or a boolean (not a string), just evaluate it once: `attr1="22"`, then in, say, your linking function: `var count = scope.$eval(attrs.attr1)`.  If it is just a constant string – `attr1="my string"` – then just use `attrs.attr1` in your directive (no need for $eval()).

See also [Vojta's google group post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/TbRQhG-G14I/bYcipV1OYwcJ) about $watch expressions.

Comment: Great answer! Do you have idea why `ng-src/ng-href` use `attr.$observe` instead of `scope.$watch` then?

Comment: @okm, since they don't create an isolate scope ([source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d551d72924f7c43a043e4760ff05d7389e310f99/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L360)), they have to use `$observe` because the attribute values contain `{{}}`s.

Comment: +1 For the AngularJS Pope! Every time I search Stack for some info on my latest Angular problem, I inevitably end up reading @MarkRajcok accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for a great post. scope.$eval(item) is really helpful. If item is a json string, it convert to an json object.

Comment: Could you compare scope.$eval and scope.$evalAsync, I sometimes use them when I want to pass in object expressions as directive parameters. Like <div my-directive="{prop: model.prop}"></div>. It allows me to put all the configuration parameters into one attribute.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, $eval evaluates an expression (on the current scope) immediately, whereas $evalAsync will evaluate the expression "[later](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync)", but before the browser renders, which is sometimes useful if you need to wait for Angular to make some DOM updates before evaluating the expression.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/17239084/215945 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17303759/215945.

Comment: @MarkRajcok - Thanks for your excellent answer. If I understand correctly, for directives with isolated scope, `$observe` and `$watch` can be used interchangeably. Is that right? Since both observers and watchers are checked every digest cycle, can I safely say that `$observe` and `$watch` have no difference in performance?

Comment: @tamakisquare, they are interchangeable when using the `@` syntax.  I believe there is no performance difference (but I haven't looked at the actual source code).

Comment: @MarkRajcok - many thanks.  This was so much clearer than any other source of info I've read.  Thank you again.

Comment: @MarkRajcok this is amazing stuff, it does take a while to get your head round though

Comment: I found some interesting cases in the following gist, where watch was required for an attribute..
https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750

Comment: @MarkRajcok and @tamakisquare, [from the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), it might suggest that $observe is more performant and also more accurate, at least when using it with `$compile`: "Use `$observe` to observe the value changes of attributes that contain interpolation (e.g. `src="{{bar}}"`). Not only is this very efficient but it's also the only way to easily get the actual value because during the linking phase the interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet and so the value is at this time set to `undefined`."

Comment: @MarkRajcok This is amazing, but it looks like AngularJS has changed a bit since 2013. I updated your Plnkr to pull in Angular 1.4.5 (without making any other changes to your code) ... http://plnkr.co/edit/ix4gUPRAkeLglLkAsBTt?p=preview ... The output to the console is different ... Could you may be talk about what has changed?

Answer (score 26):

If I understand your question right you are asking what is difference if you register listener callback with `$watch` or if you do it with `$observe`.

Callback registerd with `$watch` is fired when `$digest` is executed.

Callback registered with `$observe` are called when value changes of attributes that contain interpolation (e.g. `attr="{{notJetInterpolated}}"`).

---

Inside directive you can use both of them on very similar way:

```
    attrs.$observe('attrYouWatch', function() {
         // body
    });
```

or

```
    scope.$watch(attrs['attrYouWatch'], function() {
         // body
    });
```

Comment: Actually, since every change gets reflected in `$digest` phase, it is safe to assume that the `$observe` callback will be called in `$digest`. And `$watch` callback will also be called in `$digest` but whenever the value is changed. I think they do the exact same job: "watch the expression, call callback the value changes". The keyword difference is possibly just syntactic sugar for not confusing the developer.

Comment: @fastreload, I totally agree with your comment.. Nicely written!

Comment: @fastreload... Thanks for the wonderful explanation. If I understood correctly, Observers are for Angular Expressions. Am I right?

Comment: @PrimosK: adding you for my previous comment.

Comment: @Abilash observers are for watching dom attributes, not just expressions. So if you change the attribute value by yourself, it would be reflected in the next digest cycle.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is pretty obvious :

- $observe is used in linking function of directives.
- $watch is used on scope to watch any changing in its values.

*Keep in mind* : both the function has two arguments,

```
$observe/$watch(value : string, callback : function);
```

- **value** : is always a string reference to the watched element (the name of a scope's variable or the name of the directive's attribute to be watched)
- **callback** : the function to be executed of the form `function (oldValue, newValue)`

I have made a [<kbd>plunker</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/n4h0wjcRZDSQBeN2RyyG?p=preview), so you can actually get a grasp on both their utilization. I have used the Chameleon analogy as to make it easier to picture.

Comment: It is pretty obvious about its usages. But why was the question. Mark has summed it up beautifully.

Comment: I think the params might be switched - it appears to pass newValue, then oldValue to attrs.$observe() . . .

Answer (score 0):

Why is $observe different than $watch?

The watchExpression is evaluated and compared to the previous value each digest() cycle, if there's a change in the watchExpression value, the watch function is called.

$observe is specific to watching for interpolated values. If a directive's attribute value is interpolated, eg `dir-attr="{{ scopeVar }}"`, the observe function will only be called when the interpolated value is set (and therefore when $digest has already determined updates need to be made). Basically there's already a watcher for the interpolation, and the $observe function piggybacks off that.

See $observe & $set in [compile.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a8dedf7a015e5a3c2b74e66225a43e820a58518c/src/ng/compile.js)