# AngularJS : Why are ng-href/ng-src implemented by using attr.$observe instead of scope.$watch?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Having read [AngularJS : Difference between the $observe and $watch methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-observers-and-watchers), and [the implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/0272240400d7896224f34b9f10b492994e29c655/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L353) of `ng-href/ng-src`:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
  attr.$observe(normalized, function(value) {
    if (!value)
      return;

    attr.$set(attrName, value);
    // ...
  }
}
```

I wonder why `ng-href/ng-src` are implemented by using `attr.$observe` instead of `scope.$watch`. By using `scope.$watch`, it looks like

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
  scope.$watch(attr[normalized], function(newValue) {
    // ...
  })
}
```

then in view we could write `<img ng-href="expressionFoo">` instead of `<img ng-href="{{ expressionFoo }}">`.

The possible reasons I could figure out are

1. `attr.$observe` makes a directive to work more like a normal DOM attribute. After link, I could affect the directive by `attr.$set('ngHref', ...)` in another directive.
2. interpolate is higher level than expression. It's easier to write plain strings and multiple expressions by using interpolate.
3. `ng-href` and `ng-src` both result in string attributes, so it's safe and easier to use interpolate hence `attr.$observe` here.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think the scope isn't what you think.

Option `scope` in directives is `false` by default, which means we get parent scope, that could be anything, really.

If we want to watch for `element's attribute change`, we have to watch the `element's attribute "ng-blah"`. The scope is simply not related.

If we were to use `scope.watch`, we probably wouldn't even have a property named after that attribute, and nothing would work.