# Is there a way to ensure directive scope is resolved before using it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing an element-level directive that has a number of attributes on it.  These attributes are then put into an isolate scope using the '@' modifier.

The directive is used on a page that populates the attributes with expressions i.e

```
<my-directive attr1="{{foo.bar}}"></my-directive>
```

I'm finding that when the directive controller executes, the $scope hasn't resolved the expressions yet.  Is there a way to force the scope to resolve before entering the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't force the scope to be resolved before the controller runs.  Use [$observe](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile.directive.Attributes#%24observe) in the controller to [asynchronously](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#attributesobserve) get the value (and to be notified whenever the value changes -- just like $watch):

```
controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
    $attrs.$observe('attr1', function(newValue) {
        ....
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Does this mean I should be using $attrs instead of putting my  attribute values into an isolate scope?

Comment: @dskh, that depends on what you need your directive to do.  I suggest reading the following answer, where I go in to much more detail about $observe and $watch, with isolate scopes and non-isolate scopes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14907826/215945