# AngularJs Real Time Stock Ticker - Flash Highlight Green or Red when value changes

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am experimenting with building a real-time stock ticker app using angularjs.

app.js

```
var sa = angular.module('sa', []);

sa.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    var poll = function() {
        $http.get('/api/v1/stocks').success(
            function(stocks)
            {
            $scope.stocks = stocks;
            $timeout(poll, 2000);
            }
        );
    };

    poll();
});
```

home.html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="stock in stocks">
        <td>{{ stock.code }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock.bid }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock.ask }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The poll works fine and updates stocks correctly, however what I am looking to achieve is if the stock value increases, then animate-flash the background of that bid/ask in green. If the stock value decreases, then animate-flash the background of that bid/ask in red.

What I am looking for is for background of stock to flash red / green, then fade out to background colour.

Is there a watch / event listener function that can help me tap into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to conditionally adding and then removing a class to an element was discussed in [Angular js - Highlight dom when value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115875/angular-js-highlight-dom-when-value-changes)

The accepted answer includes [a directive, called "highlighter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115875/angular-js-highlight-dom-when-value-changes?rq=1), that temporarily adds a class when a watched value changes.  The directive can be modified slightly to apply different css classes when the change in value is an increase or decrease.  That, combined with some css transitions, is basically what you are looking for.

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/byS82/

change to highlighter directive:

```
var newclass= nv < ov ? 'highlight-red' : 'highlight-green';
```

#### HTML

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="stock in stocks track by $index" class="list" >  
    <td>{{ stock.code }}</td>
    <td highlighter="stock.bid">{{ stock.bid }}</td>  
    <td highlighter="stock.ask">{{ stock.ask }}</td>  
</tr>
```

#### CSS

```
.highlight-red {
    background-color: red;  
}
.highlight-green {
    background-color: green;  
}
td {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;  
    transition: 1s linear all;  
    background-color: clear;  
}
```

Comment: would this work for <ul> items by just changing the td to ul?

Comment: @j.witter thanks man, I am looking to bold and unbold with transition some <ul> items not in an an ng-repeat. Any chance you can give an example of how its done? Having trouble adapting this code to do it :(

Comment: I am actually able to get the code to enter the directive but the class isn't being added/removed. I want to do this on a <ul> item that is just in a div (no ng-repeat)

Comment: you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/2kvy5/.  it turns the li bold when the stock value decreases.  note - i added font size to the css transition, because font-weight doesn't animate nicely in most browsers.

Comment: Thanks mate, I've tried this http://jsfiddle.net/Ztyub/ and it seems to do more or less what I want except for the transition. Can't get it to work at all on my page though!