# How to watch property in attrs of directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that has a counter that changes from time to time.
That counter is tied to an attribute of a directive and read inside the link function of that directive.

How can I have a directive run a function each time that attr value changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Inside your corresponding `link` function: (assuming your attribute is called `counter` and your scope variable is: `scope`)

```
scope.$watch(attrs.counter, function (newTime) {
                    //do something with the new Time
});
```

Other way, surely more efficient way:

### Interpolating the attribute

Inside your directive, set the `scope` property as following (it will be isolated so):

```
scope: { counter: '@'}
```

The `counter` would automatically be observed providing the current value as long as the `link` function is called.

`'@'` better than `'='` here since you I suppose you don't set the counter to a new value in your directive, meaning you just read it. Indeed, `=` is more useful for two-way data binding but you might not need it.

Comment: Hm, is that the best way of doing that? Would it be better maybe to set `counter` inside the `scope:{...}` property? I am not sure how slow watching attrs would be.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to specify it in attrs as well when using the isolate scope with one-way `@`?

Comment: @Francisc Your DOM element should present the `counter` attribute.

Comment: Yup, just tested that and it's exactly what I need. Thanks again.

Comment: Keeping in mind that you can't use scope if another directive already uses an isolate scope.  Sometimes you are forced to watch.

Comment: Just curious about `surely more efficient way`, does the doc mention this anywhere?

Answer (score 41):

I am using this aproach:

```
.directive('mydirective',
 [function (){
    return {
      ...
      scope: {
        id: '@',
      },
      controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
         $attrs.$observe('id', function(passedId) {
           /// do what is needed with passedId
         });
    ...
```

And the directive used and id passed like this:

```
<div mydirective id="{{someprop.id}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Radim. [extra chars]

Comment: @Radim Kôhler From Mastering Web Application Dev with AngularJS book, interpolation is already the equivalent of `$observe`, you might not need to call `$observe` in your controller.

Comment: @Mik378 I would say, that from what I do experience... the observe is needed. Because if passed id is part of a promise... and directive uses it for further processing (e.g. loading data as another promise) you have to observe... to make the passed value in sync. That's how I see it now, with 1.2. Other words, if the passed value is evaluated in the moment of passing... ok. if it is part of a promise...

Comment: @Radim Köhler Maybe needed in the `controller` function, but not in the `link` function. I never tested an interpolated attribute inside a `controller` function yet.

Answer (score 12):

Use `attrs.$observe(key, fn)`. More info at [$compile.directive.Attributes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes)

```
attrs.$observe('counter',function(counter){

});
```

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907826/2874153

> $observe() is a method on the Attributes object, and as such, it can
>   only be used to observe/watch the value change of a DOM attribute. It
>   is only used/called inside directives. Use $observe when you need to
>   observe/watch a DOM attribute that contains interpolation (i.e.,
>   {{}}'s). E.g., attr1="Name: {{name}}", then in a directive:
>   attrs.$observe('attr1', ...). (If you try scope.$watch(attrs.attr1,
>   ...) it won't work because of the {{}}s -- you'll get undefined.) Use
>   $watch for everything else.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, change the directive to isolated scope and use the `=` definition.  This will set up a two-way binding for the scope property:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {

    return {
        scope: { counter: '=' }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to implement this myself and found a solution! Unfortunately, when I tried .$watch, errors were just spewing out on the console. So I used $observe instead.

Here's my solution:

```
angular.module('app').directive('aDate', [
    function() {
        return {
            template: '<span>{{date}}</span>',
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.$observe('date', function (val) {
                    var d = new Date(val);
                    element.text(d);
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

The above code changes the scoped date when the date attribute of the element  changes!

Cheers!