# How can I pass some string containing [$index] into my directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set some text on a data attribute that is used in a directive call:

```
<textarea class="pagedown-admin wmd-preview-23"
   data-modal="modal"
   data-pagedown-admin
   data-ng-model="answer.text"
   data-pid="answer.answerId"
   data-field="{{'modal.data.answers[' + $index + '].text'}}"
   id="modal-data-answer-{{$index}}"></textarea>
```

It's giving syntax errors no matter what I try. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? I want to pass in a field name with an array index **value** from inside an AngularJS ng-repeat.

```
app.directive('pagedownAdmin', function ($compile) {
    var nextId = 0;
    var markdownConverter = new Markdown.Converter();
    var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();

    converter1.hooks.chain("preBlockGamut", function (text, rbg) {
        return text.replace(/^ {0,3}""" *\n((?:.*?\n)+?) {0,3}""" *$/gm, function (whole, inner) {
            return "<blockquote>" + rbg(inner) + "</blockquote>\n";
        });
    });

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            field: '=field',
            modal: '=modal',
            pid: '=pid'
        },
        template: '<div class="pagedown-bootstrap-editor"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
```

Later in my directive I have:

```
            scope.$eval(attrs.field + "=" + rawContent);
            scope.$apply();
```

However it does not appear to get to the point of doing the $eval before it gives the error.

Here's the syntax error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$parse/syntax?p0='modal.data.answers%5B'&…7D%7D&p4='modal.data.answers%5B'%20%2B%20%24index%20%2B%20'%5D.text'%7D%7D
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.3/angular.min.js:6:449
```

Comment: Can you show some of `data-field`?  Are you using isolated scope?

Comment: @Davin - The problem is it seems to get upset before even getting to the directive. I will add the directive header to the question.

Comment: Try this: `<textarea data-field="modal.data.answers[$index].text" >`

Comment: @DavinTryon - This sends modal.data.answers[$index].text to the directive. The $index is not filled with a number as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/AWixOdol/1/edit)

#### You should write it like so:

```
<textarea data-field="{{modal.data.answers[$index].text}}" >
```

But you should also use the **Text Binding syntax** (`@`) rather than the **Two-way Binding syntax** (`=`) when referring to `field` of parent scope:

```js
scope: {
  field: '@',            
},
```

In short, `"@"` syntax supports interpolation while `"="` syntax doesn't!

**You should definitely read this**: [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)

---

#### I always like to show the source code when possible:

In [compile.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js) there is a `nodeLinkFn` function, Inside you can see these cases:

```
case '@':
  attrs.$observe(attrName, function(value) {
    isolateScope[scopeName] = value;
  });
  attrs.$$observers[attrName].$$scope = scope;
  if( attrs[attrName] ) {
    // If the attribute has been provided then we trigger an interpolation to ensure
    // the value is there for use in the link fn
    isolateScope[scopeName] = $interpolate(attrs[attrName])(scope);
  }
  break;

case '=':

  // ....... some code here

  isolateScope.$watch(function parentValueWatch() {

    //...... some code here

  }, null, parentGet.literal);
  break;
```

#### Summary :

- when using `'@'` syntax angular uses **$observe** (which internally uses **$interpolate** and **$watch**)
- when using `'='` syntax angular uses **$watch**, which does not support interpolations.
- [AngularJS : Difference between the $observe and $watch methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-observers-and-watchers)