# ng-bind happend after my directive so I don't have the value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a div element with ng-bind directive:

```
<div ng-bind="sometext"></div>
```

I have a directive that gets an element, checks its value / text and adds a color to the element according to the content. I am using this directive like that:

```
<div ng-bind="sometext" my-directive></div>
```

The problem is that on the time the directive is executing, there is no value or text on the div because ng-bind didn't happened yet.
I am getting the text using element.text().
Any idea how to make the text available inside my directive?

Comment: you will need to change the priority of your directive so that it runs after ng-bind. I've never done anything with priorities yet, so I can't give you too much help though.

Comment: @MattGreer: I thought the solution will be something like that. I saw angularJS code and there is no priority to ng-bind. I need to set less priority then ng-bind because I want my directive to run last.Any idea?

Comment: I had a similar problem last week which I solved by wrapping `$timeout` around part of my code, so it's evaluated the next digest cycle when the binding has happened. I'm not entirely happy with that solution, but perhaps it suffices for your needs.

Comment: @Naor have you tried adding `priority: 1` to your directive? just as a curiosity, maybe it really is that simple?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit 2**

The other option is to use `ng-class` or `ng-style` for changing the color of the text.  Then you don't have to create a new directive at all.

**Original Answer**

I would not depend on the `ng-bind` directive at all...  This seems much cleaner in my opinion.

```
<div ng-bind="someModel" my-directive="someModel"></div>
```

And then define your directive as...

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() { 
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.myDirective, function(newValue, oldValue) {
              // Your Code here...
            });           
        }
    };      
});
```

This way you can use your directive even if you don't have an `ng-bind` on the element (for example, if you use curly braces instead).

```
<div my-directive="someModel">{{someModel}}</div>
```

Alternatively you can use `attrs.$observe(...)` ([documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile.directive.Attributes#methods_$observe)) instead of `scope.$watch(...)`.

```
<div ng-bind="someModel" my-directive="{{someModel}}"></div>
```

and

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() { 
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('myDirective', function(interpolatedValue) {
              // Your Code here...
            });           
        }
    };      
});
```

You can find more information about the differences between `scope.$watch(...)` and `attrs.$observe()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-observers-and-watchers).

**Edit**

Given that your directive is basically mutating the DOM after the `ng-bind` directive, why not skip the `ng-bind` all together?

```
<div my-directive="{{someModel}}"></div>
```

and

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() { 
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('myDirective', function(interpolatedValue) {
              if (interpolatedValue) {
                // Modify interpolatedValue if necessary...
              }
              element.text(interpolatedValue == undefined ? '' : interpolatedValue);
            });           
        }
    };      
});
```

Comment: I used watch on an attribute value. This is the most logical thing to do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

Your directive may be running before `ngBind` has bound it's value - both your directive and `ngBind` are priority 0 so either could run first, more on that in a moment- but let's look at the [`ngBind` source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d7ed885984d58d344350ae267f51e8096bb6bea6/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js) to see the root of the problem:

```
var ngBindDirective = ngDirective(function(scope, element, attr) {
  element.addClass('ng-binding').data('$binding', attr.ngBind);

  scope.$watch(attr.ngBind, function ngBindWatchAction(value) {
    element.text(value == undefined ? '' : value);
  });

});
```

We see that `ngBind` doesn't immediately update the DOM, but rather places a watch on the `ngBind` attribute.  So the element won't be updated until that watch is run on the next `$digest` cycle (which is why a `$timeout` works).

So one option is to mimic `ngBind` and place your own watch on it's attribute- then you'll be updated whenever the `ngBind` result changes:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() { 
    return {
        priority: 1,
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngBind, function(newvalue) {
              console.log("element ",element.text());
            });           
        }
    };      
});
```

You'll note I set priority to 1.  You do need to be sure that this directive's watch is placed after the `ngBind` watch in the watch queue.  That will ensure the element has been updated by `ngBind` first.

By default a directive's link function runs post-link, so as the [`$compile` docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) note:

> Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order.

Therefore, since `ngBind` is priority 0, anything over 0 will ensure your directive's watch will come after the `ngBind` watch..

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnU4Z/1/)

Comment: Good answer ! A few words explaining why a higher priority causes the `$watch` registered in the `postLink` function to fire **after** ngBind's `$watch` would be nice :)

Comment: @ExpertSystem thanks!  Good point- I updated with a bit on that.

Comment: Unless the AngularJS team changes the priority of `ng-bind`. I would strongly suggest you don't base your code's behavior on mutating the result of `ng-bind`.

Comment: @rtcherry I get your concern.  But it's not really mutating the results of ng-bind, it's just adding a watch that follows theirs.  And, of course, Angular could change anything- but it would be tagged as a breaking change- they do publish their priorities (for example making `ngRepeat`s 1000 priority prominent).

Comment: Your code is not mutating the result, but the original question is about reading the text value and then changing color.

Comment: @rtcherry fair enough. I think of this more like chaining- for example adding another parser in the parse chain.  But I focused on "Any idea how to make the text available inside my directive?"  Overall I think having multiple ways to approach this is great for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scope.$watch in you link function and watch for model changes. Each time the value changes ng-bind will fire and your directive will be fired as well, independent to the bg-bind directive and dependent only to the modle itself.

Sorry i cant presnt you with sample code as im on a tablet while answering your question.