# Angular $parse error when updating 1.2.8

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, flash

I'm trying to update Angular 1.0.8 to 1.2.8 in one of my project.
For the while everything's ok except for one thing.

Here is the error :

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' expected : at column null of the expression [//my.url.com/some/path/mySwf.swf?someParam=en
```

Here's my DOM :

```
<embed data-embed-src embed-src="{{simulatorUrl}}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="450" allowscriptaccess="always"
           wmode="transparent" quality="high" swliveconnect="true" name="Simulator" id="Simulator"
           flashvars="">
```

Because ngSrc doesn't work I use a directive to watch src attributes :

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('embedSrc', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            var current = element;

                scope.$watch(attrs.embedSrc, function () {
                    var clone = element
                        .clone()
                        .attr('src', attrs.embedSrc);
                    current.replaceWith(clone);
                    current = clone;
                });
        }
    };
});
```

I tried few things **without success :**

- First, change sanitization : `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);`
- Disable `$sceProvider`
- Try to put my url in `$sce` trusted ressourceUrl
- Try to prefix my url with 'http:'

If my url look like : 'www.myurl.com/mySwf.swf' it works but without params unfortunately.
To test, if I put the url expression `{{simulatorUrl}}` in a `ng-href` :

```
<a ng-href="{{simulatorUrl}}">Salut</a>
```

It works like a charme. $parse doesn't throw error.

I think it's because of my directive or the `$sce` but I'm not sure.

If someone has already embed swf with angular 1.2.8, please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

`embed-src={{...}}` is an interpolated expression. At the time the post-link function os executed, interpolated expressions in Angular have to been processed yet, so `attrs.embedSrc` is basically a string with content `{{...}}`.
Thus, calling `scope.$watch(attrs.embedSrc,...)` is equivalent to calling `scope.$watch('{{..}}',...) which causes an error.

#### The solution

For observing interpolated attributes (or attributes in general), one should use Attributes' **[`$observe(key, fn)`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile.directive.Attributes#methods_$observe)** method:

> **$observe(key, fn)**
> Observes an interpolated attribute.

The observer function will be invoked once during the next $digest following compilation. The observer is then invoked whenever the interpolated value changes.

So, you should use: `attrs.$observe('embedSrc',...)`

---

For a more detailed explanation, take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-observers-and-watchers#14907826)**.

Comment: Thank's. This is ok !