# Angular Directive attrs.$observe

Tags: angularjs, directive

I found this Angular Directive online to add a twitter share button. It all seems staright forward but I can't work out what the `attrs.$observe` is actually doing.

I have looked in the docs but can't see `$observe` referenced anywhere.

The directive just seems to add the `href` which would come from the controller so can anyone explain what the rest of the code is doing?

```
module.directive('shareTwitter', ['$window', function($window) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.share = function() {

                var href = 'https://twitter.com/share';

                $scope.url = attrs.shareUrl || $window.location.href;
                $scope.text = attrs.shareText || false;

                href += '?url=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.url);
                if($scope.text) {
                    href += '&text=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.text);
                }

                element.attr('href', href);
            }

            $scope.share();

            attrs.$observe('shareUrl', function() {
                $scope.share();
            });

            attrs.$observe('shareText', function() {
                $scope.share();
            });
        }
    }
}]);


<a href="" target="_blank" share-twitter share-url="[[shareTwitterUrl]]" share-text="[[shareTwitterText]]">Twitter</a>
```

Comment: Here are the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes

Comment: Sorry I missed that completely when I looked

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**In short:**

Everytime 'shareTwitterUrl' or 'shareTwitterText' changes, it will call the share function.

**From another stackoverflow answer:** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907826/2874153)

> $observe() is a method on the Attributes object, and as such, it can
>   only be used to observe/watch the value change of a DOM attribute. It
>   is only used/called inside directives. Use $observe when you need to
>   observe/watch a DOM attribute that contains interpolation (i.e.,
>   {{}}'s).  E.g., attr1="Name: {{name}}", then in a directive:
>   attrs.$observe('attr1', ...).  (If you try scope.$watch(attrs.attr1,
>   ...) it won't work because of the {{}}s -- you'll get undefined.) Use
>   $watch for everything else.

**From Angular docs:** (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes)

> *$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe(key, fn);*
>
> Observes an interpolated attribute.
>
> The observer function will be invoked once during the next $digest fol
>   lowing compilation. The observer is then invoked whenever the interpolated value changes.

Comment: Will this value change though, I imagine it is just set once at the start of the app

Comment: Well that really depends how people choose use it ;)
But there is another good reason for doing it this way. Lets say you get the **shareTwitterUrl** from a server, this will probably take som time, then you risk that **shareTwitterUrl** have not gotten its value before the directive is initiated. So when finally **shareTwitterUrl** gets its value, the directive will be updated with the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" >
<p sr = "_{{value}}_">sr </p>


.directive('sr',function(){

return {

        link: function(element, $scope, attrs){
                attrs.$observe('sr', function() {
                                console.log('change observe')
                    });
            }
    };
})
```