# Angularjs link function firing too soon

Tags: angularjs

I have the following setup

HTML:

`<span star score="{{resto.rating}}"></span>`

A controller that downloads data and sets it in resto and the directive below.  My problem is that the link function is being called *before* the score expression has been interpolated, so I only ever get 1 star.

```
angular.module 'afmnewApp'
.directive 'star', () ->
    return {
        scope: 
            score: '@'
        template : """
            <ul class="rating">
                <li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star">
                    *
                </li>
            </ul>
        """,
        link : (scope, elem, attrs) ->
            scope.stars = []
            for x in [1..scope.score]       # should it be attrs?
                scope.stars.push({'fill'})
    }
```

Comment: a call to $scope.$digest() can udpate the view, you might need to call this function after you download the data

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work - I got an error to the effect that a $digest was already underway

Comment: as a bad workaround (can be use for dev purposes), you can test with $scope.$$phase or use $evalAsync...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue on Friday :-). I managed to find my own solution. In your case it would be :

```
angular.module 'afmnewApp'
.directive 'star', () ->
    return {
        template : """
            <ul class="rating">
                <li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star">
                    *
                </li>
            </ul>
        """,
        scope:{ 
            score: '@score'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('score', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== undefined) {
                    scope.stars = []
                    for x in [1..scope.score]
                        scope.stars.push({'fill'})
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So in the link you add a watch on your variable, so when it changes the watch will fire populating your array.

**Edit** based on Jesus comment below:

I checked about the difference between `$watch` and `$observe`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-the-observe-and-watch-methods) is a nice SO post describing it. It seems that for checking attribute changes in DOM objects (as in your case the `score` attribute of your `span` object) you should use `$observe`. For anything else you should use `$watch`. So in this case the solution should better be:

```
angular.module 'afmnewApp'
.directive 'star', () ->
    return {
        template : """
            <ul class="rating">
                <li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star">
                    *
                </li>
            </ul>
        """,
        scope:{ 
            score: '@score'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('score', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== undefined) {
                    scope.stars = []
                    for x in [1..scope.score]
                        scope.stars.push({'fill'})
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Even when your answer is technically correct, I suggest using an $observer instead of $watch here.

Comment: I have to admit that my Angular dev experience is little. I will check out the $observer and update accordingly.

Comment: @JesusRodriguez Thanks for your comment. I did some research and have updated my answer.

Comment: I marked this as the accepted answer because it does the job, but I can't help thinking there must be a better way, and that this must be a common enough situation to warrant the angular team ensuring better ordering of compilation? So I have unmarked 'accepted' for the time being