# $observe an object attribute of a directive

Tags: angularjs

My directive has an isolated scope and it receives object from the enclosing controller as an attribute.

```
app.directive('details', function() {
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            scope : {
                device : '=device',
                .
                .
                .
            },
            templateUrl : '/details.html',
            link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.$observe('device', function(value) {
                ...
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

And in HTML:

```
<details device='ctrlAlias.device' ...>
```

I read somewhere that if I want to check for changes in attribute, I need to use `$observe` function. However, most examples I saw use `$observe` on primitive values only.

I wonder how would I `$observe` a property of `device`, say `device.exist` (a boolean) and `device.id` (a string) within the `attrs.$observe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

> Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.

Whereas, [$observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) is a method on the Attributes object

> Observes an interpolated attribute.

*Code*

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return scope.device
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {    
}, true);
```

Visit [AngularJS : Difference between the $observe and $watch methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-the-observe-and-watch-methods) for more details.

Comment: see this post for more details on the difference between `$watch` and `$observe`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-the-observe-and-watch-methods

Comment: @Satpal I coded `function(newValue, oldValue) {if (typeof oldValue === "undefined") && (newValue.exist == true) {...}}` but I get undefined on the property.

Comment: @menorah84, What is the expected value `ctrlAlias.device`?

Comment: @Satpal It's a nested object. `exist` is a first-level property.