# AngularJS : Why would need $observe and $watch on the same properties?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

In the [`ngDraggable` project](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable), I found this code in the directive `ngDrag`.

```
 attrs.$observe("ngDrag", onEnableChange);
 scope.$watch(attrs.ngDrag, onEnableChange);
 attrs.$observe('ngCenterAnchor', onCenterAnchor);
 scope.$watch(attrs.ngCenterAnchor, onCenterAnchor);
```

My question is:

Why would you need both the `$observe` and `$watch` properties on the same items?

I've tried commenting each group out and it seems to make no difference at all. What is going on here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-the-observe-and-watch-methods

Comment: The `$observe`-ers were removed from the plugin: https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/commit/03ec8f51ebff9afa0ba929f1236c39c714b6439a