# AngularJS template evaluate concat expression vs auto-concat using curly braces?

Tags: angularjs, templates, angular1.6, angularjs-templates

In an angular template, how can I evaluate what of this two options is better?

1. `<img ng-src="{{filteredImgs[imgIdx].signed_src}}&width=1000">`
2. `<img ng-src="{{filteredImgs[imgIdx].signed_src + '&width=1000'}}">`

I would like to see if there are differences when dealing with errors, or performance implications between both alternatives, but I could not find the source of where those two are evaluated. (I suspect this is in angular template evaluation core)

Comment: I don't see how they can be different, but `ng-src` is interpolated with a watcher [`$observe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/angularjs-difference-between-the-observe-and-watch-methods), which is invoked whenever the interpolated value changes (in your case it's `filteredImgs[imgIdx].signed_src`) whether it is concatenated with some string or not

Comment: Then maybe one is better than the other in that one is more "elegant" code?