# AngularJS trigger a function on Attribute Changes in a Directive

Tags: angularjs

we have a directive called `actingAs` defined as below.

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive('actingAs', function () {
    return {
        controller: 'ActingAsController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            'onself': '&onSelf',
            'onuser': '&onUser',
            'onupdate': '&onUpdate',
            'actingAsFullNm': '=',
            'actingAsType': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {
            attributes.$observe('actingAsFullNm', function (oldval, newval) {
                console.log("In Observe Function");
                if (oldval != newval) {
                    console.log( 'Acting as FullNmae changed from : '+oldval+' to: '+newval);
                }
                else  {
                    console.log('Acting as FullNmae oldval :' + oldval + ' newVal: ' + newval);
                }
            });
        },
        templateUrl: 'actingAs.directive.html'
    };
});
```

its used as below on the Page

```
<acting-as on-self="vm.runAsSelf()" on-user="vm.runAsUser(user, type)" on-update="vm.update(idsid)"
               acting-as-full-nm="vm.actingAsFullNm" acting-as-type="vm.actingAsType"></acting-as>
```

The `vm.actingAsFullNm` is updated on the parent page scope where this directive is place. we want to trigger a function or do something in the directive controller upon this value change.
Hence we are using the Link function in the directive definition .
But for some reason Link function is only being executed once when page loads. Further changes to `vm.actingAsFullNm` are not triggering Link function. Not sure what are we missing.

### Edit:

I also used scope.$watch as below

```
link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {
            scope.$watch('actingAsFullNm', function (oldval, newval) {
                console.log("In Observe Function");
                if (oldval != newval) {
                    console.log( 'Acting as FullNmae changed from : '+oldval+' to: '+newval);
                }
                else  {
                    console.log('Acting as FullNmae oldval :' + oldval + ' newVal: ' + newval);
                }
            });
        },
```

still the Console.log in link function is executed only once..not when the value changes

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need you need to use $watch instead.

observe vs watch
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907826/5781575

Comment: Yes I did..added it as Edit..still no luck...the Console do not print any statements in Link Function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AngularJs version >= 1.5, i would suggest you to change your directive to component(Components have a well-defined lifecycle which is close to new Angular), and you can detect the changes via **$onChanges** hook.

If you do not have plan to change it to component, you can use scope.watch as the other one suggested.

```
scope.$watch('actingAsFullNm', function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Yes..I tried using scope.$watch (pls check my edit) still no luck...:(. I am using Angularjs 1.5.11

Comment: Really cannot find any issue from what you have posted. Maybe you could reproduce the issue with stackbliz, and we can help you on that?