# Angular directive for a fallback image

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If an image on a separate server doesn't exist I'd like to display a default image. Is there an angular directive to accomplish this?

Comment: Not that I've seen, but it wouldn't be hard to write one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if a ngSrc path resolves to a 404, is there a way to fallback to a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310298/if-a-ngsrc-path-resolves-to-a-404-is-there-a-way-to-fallback-to-a-default)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

No but you can create one.

http://jsfiddle.net/FdKKf/

**HTML:**

```
<img fallback-src="http://google.com/favicon.ico" ng-src="{{image}}"/>
```

**JS:**

```
myApp.directive('fallbackSrc', function () {
  var fallbackSrc = {
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      iElement.bind('error', function() {
        angular.element(this).attr("src", iAttrs.fallbackSrc);
      });
    }
   }
   return fallbackSrc;
});
```

Comment: Nice! I only want to add, that if he hasn't jQuery included, he should write
iElement.on('error',function() {

Comment: Not sure why I put `angular.element` but `iElement` may have worked too

Comment: how do you enforce the same size on this image that applies to the images you are "falling back" on?

Comment: thru css or width and height attributes. Assuming that they all will be of the same size.

Comment: This is a good directive. I had a problem with it because the ng-src could also be a null value. Here was my fix. I hope it helps. https://gist.github.com/jpotts18/7161375

Comment: Note that the standard onerror attribute works fine as well unless there's interpolation within the fallback value.

Comment: just use `iAttrs.$set('src', iAttrs.fallbackSrc)`

Comment: Instead, I would use $(element).one(...) (or unbind the event after it is consumed) to ensure you don't get a recursive error handling loop if the  replacement image doesn't exist.

Comment: This works, but not smooth enough. In case the image not found, you may see for the some short time a default browser icon for "missing resource", and right after that it being replaced by image from 'fallback-src'. So user sees kind of flick, and personally I think this is not good experience.

Comment: I've tried similar one for `audio` it seems doesn't work for `audio` 404's . any idea ?

Comment: How do you invoke some function instead? for example, if image is not loaded, raise modal with error notice

Comment: @Dalibor instead of this line

`angular.element(this).attr("src", iAttrs.fallbackSrc);`

You need to add the code to invoke the modal.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an angular directive...

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-img-fallback

Github: https://github.com/dcohenb/angular-img-fallback

*(32 stars as of now)*

Answer (score 2):

**Angualr 2 Version**

https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-img-fallback

**HTML**

```
<img fallback-src="http://google.com/favicon.ico" src="http://google.com/failedImage.png"/>
```

**Angular 2 Component**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[fallback-src]'
})
export class FallbackSrc {

  @Input('fallback-src') imgSrc: string;
  private el: HTMLElement;
  private isApplied: boolean = false;
  private EVENT_TYPE: string = 'error';

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
    this.el.addEventListener(this.EVENT_TYPE, this.onError.bind(this))
  }

  private onError() {
    this.removeEvents();

    if (!this.isApplied) {
      this.isApplied = true;
      this.el.setAttribute('src', this.imgSrc);
    }
  }

  private removeEvents() {
    this.el.removeEventListener(this.EVENT_TYPE, this.onError);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.removeEvents();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own fallback lib.

A pretty simple and straightforward angular fallback image lib:

https://github.com/alvarojoao/angular-image-fallback

Utility to work with loading images and handling image error, has image-holder to handle errors in image loading and image-loading for images loading placeholders

http://alvarojoao.github.io/angular-image-fallback

### Usage

Just add the image attribute to your `<img />` tags

```
<img image="{{'path/to/img.jpg'}}" />
```

**Make** **sure** you don't use `ng-src` as your image `src` attribute.

### Advanced options

#### with custom fallback and loading placeholders:

```
<img image="{{image.url}}" image-loading="/image/loading.gif" 
     image-holder="/image/error.png" />
```

### Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/alvarojoao/4wec4gsq/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

I think this will also work

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img[imgFallback]',
})

export class DefaultImageDirective{ 
  public defaultImg: string = './assets/img/default-image-placeholder.svg';
  @Input() src!: string;

  @HostBinding('src') 
  get originalSrc() {
    return this.src;
  }

  @HostListener('error') onError() {
    this.src = this.defaultImg;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<img imgFallback [src]="productItemImage" alt="Sample alt text" />
```