# Angularjs ng-show/ng-if not working properly for images

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting Image dynamically if image with that name is present in that folder then image should be visible if no image in folder image tag must be hidden, for that I used ng-show/ng-if but some times it hides if no image in folder and some time it don't hides if no image in folder.I used both ng-if and ng-show but no luck.

here is my sample code

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in teams">
    <td>
       <span ng-if="img/gflag/{{team._id}}.png">
         <img  ng-src="img/gflag/{{team._id}}.png">
       </span>
     </td>
  </tr>


    <tr ng-repeat="team in teams">
      <td>
       <span ng-show="img/gflag/{{team._id}}.png">
         <img  ng-src="img/gflag/{{team._id}}.png">
       </span>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: ng-show and ng-if waiting a boolean

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310298/if-a-ngsrc-path-resolves-to-a-404-is-there-a-way-to-fallback-to-a-default

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16349631/3083093