# ng-src in Angular 2 js with Dart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dart, angular

In angular version 1 i use ng-src to load an url.
In angular 2 Js for Dart i can't find a similar method to load resources.
For example in Angular 1 js:

```
 <img class="cover" src="images/cover_placeholder.png" data-ng-src="{{coverUrl}}"
```

in Angular 2 js i have already tried:

```
 <img class="cover" src="{{coverUrl}}">
```

How i can load a placeholder in case of image is not available?
There areothers smart ways to do that?

**EDIT**
Solved in this way:

```
   <img class="class-image" onError="this.src='./images/cover_placeholder.png';" src="{{coverUrl}}" >
```

If image is not avaible place the Placeholder image.

Comment: what do you mean with image not available? is the variable undefined or the image returns a 404

Comment: get to the image url returns a 404

Comment: Are you using a directive? Don´t see how that case would be resolved with angular 1

Comment: i use dart with angular2 Javascript

Comment: You would probably need to do something like this but with angular2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349578/angular-directive-for-a-fallback-image

Comment: What's the problem with `src="{{coverUrl}}"`? I haven't found anything about `data-ng-src`. Can you please provide a link?

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on when you are getting the error. If it is erroring on load, it is because Angular hasn't kicked off by the time the html is loaded and so the url cannot be interpreted.

In AngularJS, this was circumvented by using `ng-src`

The Angular two equivalent is to use `[src]=""`

```
<img class="cover" [src]="coverUrl">
```

Comment: Thes two equivalents should be split where one uses `[]` and the other `{{}}` ;-) Both at the same time are invalid.

Comment: You are correct, I've updated my answer! Just a copy and paste error from the OP's question. SO needs a compiler!