# onerror is working on ng-src but not on anchor tag

Tags: javascript

Obective  : to display a default image  on an anchor tag if no image is available

onerror is working on ng-src   but not

not working

```
<li class=""><a href="http://imagepath/correct.jpg" id="hrefID"      onerror="this.src='http://imagepath/default.jpg'  "title="default image"</a>
```

This is working however not clickable

```
  <img alt="1" ng-   src="http://imagepath/correct.jpg" onerror="this.src='http://imagepath/default.jpg '"title="default image" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by `onerror is working on ng-src but not    not working`?

Comment: it works  <img alt="1" ng-   src="http://imagepath/correct.jpg" onerror="this.src='http://imagepath/default.jpg '"title="default image" />
 but    not on an clickable anchor tag
Obective : to display a default image on an anchor tag if no image is available

onerror is working on ng-src but not

not working

<li class=""><a href="http://imagepath/correct.jpg" id="hrefID"      onerror="this.src='http://imagepath/default.jpg'

Comment: `onerror` on `img` often misfires. Better go for a one of the directives discussed here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349578/angular-directive-for-a-fallback-image

Answer (score 1):

Angular directive ngSrc doesn't have any native features for processing of 404 response.

So you can try like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="image in images">
        <img ng-src="{{image}}" on-error="http://google.com/favicon.ico"/>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('onError', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('error', function() {
        if (attrs.src != attrs.onError) {
          attrs.$set('src', attrs.onError);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.images = [
        'http://www.titanui.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/30/Flat-AngularJS-Logo-PSD.png',
        'any.png' //WRONG URL
    ];
});
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/25954/)

Comment: work perfectly onerror="this.src='image/path'"    using ng-src      just don't know the equivalent onerror syntax for   anchor tag  i.e.  this.href= ???

Comment: onerror does not work on anchor tag. I works on <img>, <input type="image">, <object>, <script> and <style>