# Define a default image if the variable {{image}} is empty

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-template

My `<img>`:

```
<img width="90" height="90"  src="{{image}}" />
```

Default image folder: `assets/img/pic_user.png`

How can I define a default image that is not defined in the variable: `{{image}}` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Logical OR operator `||`

```
<img width="90" height="90"  src="{{image||'assets/img/pic_user.png'}}" />
```

Answer (score 7):

You can store default image route in variable and then use ternary operator to use it in case `image` doesn't exist:

```
defaultImage: string = "assets/img/pic_user.png";
```

And then in your template:

```
<img width="90" height="90"  [src]="image ? image : defaultImage" />
```

Notice that I used property binding instead of interpolation, it is much more elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick to set default values in JavaScript:

```
var a = newValue || 0;
```

Same also works for Angular. 
In your case:

```
<img width="90" height="90" src="{{image || 'assets/img/pic_user.png' }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a fallback image

```
<img fallback-src="fallbackimg" ng-src="{{image}}"/>

myApp.directive('fallbackSrc', function () {
  var fallbackSrc = {
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      iElement.bind('error', function() {
        angular.element(this).attr("src", iAttrs.fallbackSrc);
      });
    }
   }
   return fallbackSrc;
});
```

from: [Angular directive for a fallback image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349578/angular-directive-for-a-fallback-image)