# How to hide broken images in Angular app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've built an Angular app that utilizes the Instagram API to pull in images. If a user later deletes an image I end up with broken images (404's).
I've attempted to use jQuery to hide the div containing these (broken) images, but they still appear.

I've placed the following jQuery in a 'custom.js' file that I reference in my 'index.html' file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").error(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

I reference jQuery then 'custom.js' in the head of 'index.html' as follows:

```
<script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

...and here is the html I'm attempting to apply this jQuery to:

```
<a ng-href="{{image.link}}" target="_blank" title="{{image.text}}"><img ng-src="{{image.img}}" alt="" class="img-responsive" ng-style="homeColors" id="image"></a>
```

Comment: Why not remove it? You don't need to show it again.

Comment: @cychoi, removing would be an option, too. The problem is that the jQuery above isn't currently working at all, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: The code you provided works. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/fqxw0dqg/

Comment: @cychoi, interesting. I wonder if the fact that my images sit inside an `ng-repeat` causes the jQuery to not work.

Comment: Not sure. I've never been using angularJS, so I can't speak for that. If you can provide more code on that in your question, people here might help.

Comment: Okay. I updated the fiddle using `ng-repeat` and, unfortunately, it still works. http://jsfiddle.net/fqxw0dqg/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the following Javascript to hide my images. The first function hides the grandparent of my image so that the entire div is hidden. The second function replaces missing user profile images with Instagram's anonymous user image:

```
function imgError(image){
  image.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
function anonImg(image){
  image.src = 'https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg';
}
```

Just add the following HTML to the respective images:

```
onerror="imgError(this);"
onerror="anonImg(this);"
```

Comment: I thought this would be the way to go too. Problem I run into, an error with any image causes all to hide -- I'm actually responding to onerror="this.style.display='none'"

Answer (score 0):

Try removing src attribute from broken images instead, but i think this still may not work, because angular could bring this attribute back.

If this won't work, please try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17122325/4229156

Comment: The "best" option I've found so far is to use this HTML tag: `onerror="this.style.display='none'"` The problem is, this only hides the image. I need to hide the containing div.