# AngularJS ng-src condition if Not Found (via url)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I am porting a bunch of images that I stored locally to an online resource that stays up to date. Originally when I stored the images locally I could use the following condition for my images.

```
<img ng-src="/Content/champions/{{Champions1[champ1-1].cName.trim() || 'None'}}.png"
```

This would grab the current image pathway based off a name, and if it did not exist it would simply return the image path of `/Content/champions/None.png`

I figured this would work the same way via a url. So I made the syntax.

```
<img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.20.1/img/champion/{{Champions1[champ1-1].cName.trim() 
|| 
'/Content/champions/None'}}.png"
```

What I assumed would occur, is that if the above URL returned `404 (Not Found)`, it would default back to my local storage for the None image. However, it still tries to display an online image and shows the "broken image/picture" icon rather than conditioning over the to my local "None" image.

How might I fix this? Or why is Angular not responding correctly to this scenario when it is saying Not Found `404 (Not Found)`?

Sometimes it tries to add the conditioned syntax to the URL rather than re-looking in the home directory, could that be the problem? i.e. It sometimes returns the following rather than restarting from my Content folder. `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.20.1/img/champion//Content/champions/None.png`

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17122325/356380

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if a ngSrc path resolves to a 404, is there a way to fallback to a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310298/if-a-ngsrc-path-resolves-to-a-404-is-there-a-way-to-fallback-to-a-default)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
{{Champions1[champ1-1].cName || 'None'}}
```

This construction would replace your image name with `'None'` only when your image is null or undefined.

Angular directive `ngSrc` doesn't have any native features for processing of 404 response.

But it would be fixed with the following `onErrorSrc` directive.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('onErrorSrc', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind('error', function() {
            if (attrs.src != attrs.onErrorSrc) {
              attrs.$set('src', attrs.onErrorSrc);
            }
          });
        }
    }
});

<img ng-src="wrongUrl.png" on-error-src="http://google.com/favicon.ico"/>
```

See example on [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9303/)

Comment: I got this working, but I had to use "src" instead of "ng-src".
<img src="wrongUrl.png" on-error-src="http://google.com/favicon.ico"/>

Comment: aaaa that directive works brilliantly! much better than my previous solution  onerror="this.src='./img/400blank.png'" , which was not playing nicely with AngularJS. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 35):

Other simple solution is use the following code, that perform the same final result:

```
<img ng-src="{{ yourImageCurrentScopeVar }}" onerror="this.src='img/default-image-when-occur-a-error.png'"/>
```

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, it works @BiswasKhayargoli-ITH could you tell me more about your experience and your environment with this directive?

Comment: so this answer works but can cause the image to show the error image if AngularJS is too slow to load. The directive solution above is more robust

Answer (score 12):

I used this:

```
            <img ng-src="{{ '/api/whatever/' + id + '/image/' }}"
                onerror="angular.element(this).scope().imgError()"
                onload="angular.element(this).scope().imgLoaded()" />
```

imgError() and imgLoaded() are functions in the controller for this page. This technique is especially suitable for my purposes, because in it I set a scope variable to hide the image entirely when it's not loaded, and replace it with an internationalized text message about the fact that the image isn't found.

Comment: This totally works! I wanted to filter the image in controller and this works.

Comment: This may not work if [debug data is disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data): ```$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);```.

Answer (score 1):

Other possiblity to call a function on your Java Script

```
<img ng-src="{{yourImageCurrentScopeVar}}" onerror="myFunction(this)"/>

<script>
function myFunction(event) {
event.src = "./Static/app/img/by_default_picture.png";
event.onerror = '';
};
</script>
```