# how to deal with ng-src with invalid url in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, image, angularjs-ng-repeat, src

I would like to show the picture of a user if there is a user in my object list (profileList), and default/error  as defaultProfile.png when no user is found ({{item.userProfile}} is null)

I have searched for similar approaches such as

[angularjs: ng-src equivalent for background-image:url(…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549134/angularjs-ng-src-condition-if-not-found-via-url)

and

[empty ng-src doesn't update image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092687/empty-ng-src-doesnt-update-image)

My approach to this problem is:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in profileList">
    <div>
     <img src='assets/img/defaultProfile.png' data-ng-src="http://example.com/{{item.userProfile}}.jpg" onerror="this.src='assets/img/defaultProfile.png'" />
    </div>
<div>
```

I am able to show error photo however I am still getting error 500,

> GET http://example.com/.jpg 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

How to avoid getting http://example.com//.jpg?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `ng-if` and `ng-hide`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in profileList">
    <div>
     <img ng-if="item.userProfile" 
          data-ng-src="http://example.com/{{item.userProfile}}.jpg" />
     <img ng-hide="item.userProfile" 
          src="assets/img/defaultProfile.png" />
    </div>
<div>
```

When `item.userProfile` exists, show the `ng-src` and hide the default otherwise vice versa.

Comment: I have tried the method as above but still getting status 500 error. My list is $scope.profileList = {fullName:"xxx", userProfile:null }. I have tried to set userProfile as null, string.empty and not defining but none works, any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your current issue is `ng-src` is still compiled and evaluated to an invalid url when `userProfile` is undefined.

A simple solution is to use ternary and check for `userProfile` before deciding with url should be rendered:

```
 <img ng-src="{{ item.userProfile ? 'http://example.com/' + item.userProfile + '.jpg'}} : 'assets/img/defaultProfile.png'" />
```

It will guarantee that you will always fetch the default image unless `item.userProfile` is available.

Answer (score 1):

It works.

> ng-show

will run no matter {{item.userProfile}} is null or not.

By changing it to

> ng-if

Below code is working:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in profileList">
<div>
 <img ng-if="item.userProfile" 
      data-ng-src="http://example.com/{{item.userProfile}}.jpg" />
 <img ng-if="item.userProfile == null" 
      src="assets/img/defaultProfile.png" />
</div>
```

note that my profileList is:

```
$scope.profileList = {userProfile = null}
```

Thanks a lot