# Replace with default image if image not found -angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

What could be the best possible condition to check and display if the image path is undefined in AngularJS.
I have tried like this:

```
HTML:
<div ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" == "null" || src="img/avatar.png" >

CONTROLLER:
$scope.imageUrl="125.178.1.127/uploads/image" +$scope.imageName;
```

If $scope.imageName is undefined I have to load/show the default image `img/avatar.png`

Comment: possible duplicate of [if a ngSrc path resolves to a 404, is there a way to fallback to a default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310298/if-a-ngsrc-path-resolves-to-a-404-is-there-a-way-to-fallback-to-a-default)

Comment: But my condition dosen't resolve to a 404.It gets undefined instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div ng-src="{{imageName ? imageUrl : 'img/avatar.png'}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Angular Image Fallback](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-img-fallback) modul and perfectly works! Just place fallback-src and loading-src to the image tag.

In your modul:

```
angular.module('starter', ['dcbImgFallback'])
```

In your HTML:

```
<img ng-src="your image path" fallback-src="your image default" loading-src="your image loading">
```

This is also works in ng-repeat. Hope this can helps.