# Having trouble with background image in div.style angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, google-chrome

using expressjs, chrome, angular:

I'm trying to add

```
<div style="background: url({{ data.image }});"></div>
```

it works fine, but after several reloads(~3-5) of page image stops to display, network tab shows (pending) in status, although, chrome dev. tools show all the time that the style is set to `"background url(http://localhost:4000/media/cover.jpg)"`

Tried to turn off caching in as possible reason - didn't help. Wrapping into `ng-style` did the same. Firefox works fine.

**Solved by editing server.js:**

used in server.js

```
  app.get('/:addr', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.addr === 'media') {
      return next();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Here is a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781685/angularjs-ng-src-equivalent-for-background-imageurl.

Comment: Found the reason:
server.js has `app.get('/:addr', function(req,res){});` that possible catches the image request. But don't know for now what to do with that.

Comment: @pvf, write your solution as regular answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason: server.js has app.get('/:addr', function(req,res){}); that possible catches the image request. But don't know for now what to do with that.