# Change background Image in a Class using Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have class named **"tp-cont"** which is loaded from a different .css file. I could change the background image using jQuery using the below code.

**In HTML:**

```
<li ng-click="changeTemplateBackgroundImage()"></li>
```

**In Controller:**

```
$scope.changeTemplateBackgroundImage = function(){

        var imageUrl = 'public/uploads/Admin/template_themes/1/black.png';
        $('.tp-cont').css('background-image','url(' + imageUrl + ')');

    };
```

I want to know if there a work around for the same using **angularjs**

Thanks is advance.

> Answer given below:

**In Controller :**

```
$scope.changeTemplateBackgroundImage = function(){

        $scope.bgUrl = 'public/uploads/Admin/template_themes/1/black.png';

    };
```

**In HTML :**

```
<div class="tp-cont" ng-style="{ 'background-image': 'url({{bgUrl}})' }">
```

Comment: See this: You can create a custom directive for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781685/angularjs-ng-src-equivalent-for-background-imageurl

Comment: why go far? what about `ng-class`?

Comment: Do you have access to this .css file? can you change it?

Comment: I mean - can you add clsses to the css file itself? adding code lines to it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Controller :**

```
$scope.changeTemplateBackgroundImage = function(){

        $scope.bgUrl = 'public/uploads/Admin/template_themes/1/black.png';

    };
```

**In HTML :**

```
<div class="tp-cont" ng-style="{ 'background-image': 'url({{bgUrl}})' }">
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can create a directive and use the $element

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

you can also do this directly in your controller. It is alos possible to use vanile js with document.getElementById

Answer (score 1):

```js
$scope.changeTemplateBackgroundImage = function(){

        var imageUrl = 'public/uploads/Admin/template_themes/1/black.png';
        var element = document.getElementByClassName("tp-cont");
        element.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+imageUrl')';

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-style`, like

`<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>`, set the `myStyle` string in your function.