# Error from directive when element is removed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using an ad-hoc `ngIf` directive for Angular 1.0.3 acquired from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077471/conditional-logic-in-angularjs-template).

```
// effectively
app.directive("ngIf", function () {                                             
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {                                 
            if (scope.$eval(attrs.ngIf)) {                                      
            } else {                                                            
                element.replaceWith(' ');                                       
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
});
```

The element actually gets removed.  If the element has `ng-model` (and possibly other directives) Angular will complain.

```
<input ng-if="msg == 'foo'" ng-model=msg>
```

If `msg` is not `foo`, we get

> Error: No controller: ngModel

This most likely has to do with the element being removed when ngModel is evaluated.

Is there any way to rewrite the `ngIf` directive so that the error does not occur?

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/h78X4/1/)

Comment: I think that you put the wrong JSFiddle link :P

Comment: If you replace the element as you are doing, how will you ever add the content back when ngIf evaluates to true? Your directive no longer has an anchor in the DOM to insert content into. How did you plan for it to work?

Comment: @Adam that's probably an excellent question, but I didn't make that directive.  I'm not sure that that's what it was designed for

Comment: @JesusRodriguez you are absolutely right; fixed

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
element.replaceWith(' ');
```

use

```
element.html('');
```

And it works fine.  Here's a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/sd3px/

This way you're not removing the Angular attributes that were established at compile time.

Angular gets rather sad when an element is established at compile time and then is gone at link.

You can see how Angular "recreates elements using their compiled state" in it's own version of `ngif` (new as of 1.1.5): https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/4612705ec297bc6ba714cb7a98f1be6aff77c4b8/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js

**Update with 1.2 test:**

I was curious to see how this works with 1.2.0.  Admittedly you'd probably just use Angular's `ngif` with 1.2.  None the less your code does work in 1.2 with one minor change of using `element.html('');` instead of `replaceWith`.

Here's a plunker showing that in action:  http://plnkr.co/edit/5jUzTH43OF2PqzMEbSz4?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately the `.html` solution does not remove the element itself (which is part of the problem, I'm sure)

Comment: Right- angular bound to the ng-model you created during the compile step.  Obliterating it during link causes the problem you're seeing.  Is it critical the surrounding element be gone?  If so do you always know the name of the ng-model you'll have?  We have to keep compile and link phases in sync one way or another.

Comment: Well the element with `ngIf` on it is an `<input>` so it's not actually surrounding anything per se

Comment: I see what you're saying - I was thinking of my example.  Would it be reasonable to use a surrounding div that has the `ng-if` on it, like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/sd3px/1/  ?

Comment: Well that is the solution I'd come up with, but I was wondering if there was a way to have the directives work properly together in this way.

Comment: I'm assuming you're pre 1.1.5, otherwise you could use the Angular ngif.  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngIf

Comment: Interesting to read the Angular version of ngif.  Note the comments about how they recreate the compiled state elements.  You could reproduce that- if you really want to....  (since I think that's exactly the issue you're running into):  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/4612705ec297bc6ba714cb7a98f1be6aff77c4b8/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js