# Inline-logic in templates in AngularJS

Tags: templates, angularjs

Is there any way to write logic inline in a template in AngularJS.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.isValid ? 'Valid item' : 'Invalid Item'}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use `&&` and `||`, which will end up working just like the ternary operators.

`{{item.isValid && 'Valid' || 'Invalid' }}`

**EDIT: Angular introduced ternary operators in 1.1.5:**

`{{item.isValid ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid' }}`

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I was looking for. They mention in the documentation that there can be "expressions" inside the curly-braces and now I understand better how to use them. Thanks.

Comment: Angular introduced ternarys in 1.1.5. See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-angular-templates-angularjs/12151492#12151492

Comment: Just wondering, is there any potential problems using an unescaped '&' in HTML? Might the browser produce validation errors before angular renders the templates?

Comment: @kapace , did you find an answer to your comment?

Comment: @Eric, No, I have just ignored this issue, but it gets highlighted by my editor as a problem.

Comment: Only a small point but took me a minute to figure it out, you're missing a single quote at the of Invalid, i.e. it should read:

{{item.isValid ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid'}}

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a span with ng-show to show your conditional text

**Example**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span ng-show="item.isValid">
           Valid item
    </span>
    <span ng-show="!item.isValid">
           Invalid item
    </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly the bloated solution I was afraid of... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't use conditionals in angular expressions. And, if your div content is light (just text), you might want to use ng-bind (it also saves you from having additional span element):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind="{true: 'Valid item', false: 'Invalid item'}[item.isValid]"></div>
```