# angularjs simple conditional

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pug

I know I can use ng-if to do conditionals like this:

```
  td.icon(ng-if="isAuthor()", colspan="2")
  td.icon(ng-if="!isAuthor()", colspan="3")
```

But it seems a bit over-wordy for something simple. Is there a way to do:

```
  td.icon(ng-if="!isAuthor()", colspan="{{if isAuthor(): 2 else 3}}")
```

Comment: Angular added support for the ternary operator (which is what you are asking about) in 1.1.5 - [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-angular-templates-angularjs)

Comment: What's this syntax? Angular goes on HTML. Like `<td colspan="{{isAuthor() ? 2 : 3}}">`. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function that does that!

```
td.icon(colspan="getColspan()")
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.getColspan = function () {
    if (isAuthor()) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
};
```

Comment: There's no built in conditional evaluation in the expression right?