# AngularJS - Can I use data binding value depending on ternary operator

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat **li** elements and I want to set a specific value for that **li** depending on whether a function returns true or false and I don't want to do it in the controller because I have dependency issues where it makes it Minimize or Maximize for ALL **li** elements but I want it to be for each individual **li** element. I tried using several things including the following without any luck. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I would appreciate any input or any other way of doing this.

object1 is from an ng-repeat that includes this **li** element.

```
<li><a tabindex="-1" ng-click="setHidden(object1)">{isItHidden(object1) ? 'Minimize' : 'Maximize'}</a></li>
```

**SOLUTION (thanks to jdp)**

```
<li><a tabindex="-1" ng-click="setHidden(object1)">{{isItHidden(object1)}}</a></li>

$scope.isItHidden = function(object){
    return object.hidden ? 'Maximize' : 'Minimize';
}
```

Comment: kindly share complete html and js file object1 is not visible in the code

Comment: You can't do logic like that in a view. Why couldn't you have `$scope.isItHidden(obj)` return either 'Minimize' or 'Maximize? If you're passing in the specific object as a function parameter there shouldn't be any interference. Could you share your controller and some sample data?

Comment: @jdp, that worked as well!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this

```
{{ object1.hidden && 'Minimize' || 'Maximize' }}
```

In angular 1.2 a real ternary operator will be added.

Comment: Now when 1.2 is released, the ternary operator is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-angular-templates-angularjs

Comment: Can i also pass the value like this -->  {{ object1.hidden && '{{value1}}' || '{{value2}}' }}  ?

Answer (score 33):

With the release of angular 1.2, you can now use the more intuitive ternary operator inside `ng-bind`

```
<a ng-bind="object1.hidden ? 'Maximize' : 'Minimize'"></a>
```

or inside brackets

```
<a>{{ object1.hidden ? 'Maximize' : 'Minimize' }}</a>
```