# Json Output in another Json output?

Tags: angularjs, json

Sry for the bad title,

I have this code:

```
{{status ? 'Your VIP Status is Active' {{aboend}} : 'Your VIP Status is not Active'}}
```

But it dont work, because {{}} in another {{}} looks like dont work...

In this case we got a Abonoment and we want to know the status, and if it is active, then i want to dispaly on what date it ends. When i place the Abo End Information outside of the {{status}} then it is shown everytime... But if they dont got any VIP then the Date is 00.00.0000... This is useless =/

But there must be any way to realize that, have anyone any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682658/angularjs-can-i-use-data-binding-value-depending-on-ternary-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to do something like this?

```
{{status ? ('Your VIP Status is Active' + aboend) : 'Your VIP Status is not Active'}}
```

Comment: ohh great! Thanks alot!