# How to show angularjs expression in ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

actually i want to show angularjs expression in ternary operator,Is it possible to show expression in ternary operator if yes then can some one guide me.Thanks in advance.

This is what i have tried but its not work.

```
{{ jdFile ? "Job Description File : {{fileName}}"  : "Resume File :{{fileName}}" }}

{{ jdFile ? "Job Description File : '[fileName]'"  : "Resume File :'[fileName]'" }}

{{ jdFile ? "Job Description File : 'fileName'"  : "Resume File :'fileName'" }}
```

Where jdFile is a Boolean value and fileName is a expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682658/angularjs-can-i-use-data-binding-value-depending-on-ternary-operator

Comment: may be you can try : 
`{{ jdFile ? "Job Description File : " +fileName  : "Resume File :"+fileName }}`

Comment: @Rahul that is different question

Comment: @Rahul Thank you so much man,its work

Comment: Glad that help. I shall post this as answer. please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please use below code :

```
{{ jdFile ? "Job Description File : " +fileName : "Resume File: "+fileName }}
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

use: `{{ jdFile ? "Job Description File" : "Resume File" }} {{fileName}}`

toggle the text on the basis of your `jdFile` flag, and your `fileName` variable is used in both so place it at the end.

Comment: Sachet Gupta Thanks for the reply,yes its also working.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Following Code may work for you:

```
{{ jdFile ? "Job Description File : " +fileName : "Resume File: "+fileName }}
```