# AngularJS versioning

Tags: angularjs

This is a newbie question. On the [AngularJS site](http://www.angularjs.org/), there is a link to download AngularJS. The download button says "1.0.8/1.2.0-rc.2". I'm confused. Which version of AngularJS am I downloading?

The reason I need to know is because I really need the ternary operator feature. From my understanding, that was added in 1.1.5 ([per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-angular-templates-angularjs)). However, I do not see the word 'ternary' anywhere in the code referenced by the download button.

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the download button, you get a dialog. In this dialog you can choose between the latest stable and unstable release.

When you choose stable, you will get 1.0.8. If you choose unstable, you will get 1.2.0-rc.2. You can then use the CDN link or download the sources yourself by clicking on the download button.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Angular versions later than 1.0.8 from the following link:

http://code.angularjs.org/

**Edit:**
As Mark suggests you can also select "unstable" to download 1.2.0-rc.2