# Angular Js binding text input with model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a very simple code to bind the user text input to the model. 
The text box prompts the user to enter the name & says hello "username" on enter.
But I also want Hello to appear only when the user enters the name.
Can anyone help me with that. Currently Hello is present by default.

ui page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/prac_controller.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>prac_one</title>
</head>
<body ng-app>

<div ng-controller="pracOne">
Enter the name<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="message.text"/>
<p>Hello, {{message.text}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

controller

```
function pracOne($scope)
{
$scope.message={text:""};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p>{{message.text ? 'Hello, ' + message.text : message.text}}</p>
```

Or

```
<p>{{message.text && 'Hello, '+message.text || message.text}}</p>
```

Update: You can use `ngShow` if you want to conditionally display an element:

```
<p><span ng-show="message.text != ''">Hello, </span>{{message.text}}</p>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply; can u plz explain why && and || are used; is there any link from where I can refer.
message.text will display whatever the user types then after that will the && do?

Comment: @ShivangSarawagi I have updated the answer. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-angular-templates-angularjs

Comment: can I use jquery for DOM manipulation with angularJS? like instead of ternary operator use the jquery hide, show method?

Comment: Ofcourse you can. But why to do that when there's a very simpler way of doing the same?

Comment: @ShivangSarawagi You might like using Angular's `ngShow` or `ngHide` directive.