# Angular JS using conditions in {{}} expression

Tags: angularjs

I have to display either 0 or 1 in {{}} in HTML page. my controller has a property based on which i have to decide wether to display 0 or to display 1. If the property is greater than or equal to one then 1 should be displayed, 0 otherwise.

Any suggestions or tricks ?

Note: I want to do this in HTML code itself using angularJS tricks.

Please Help

Comment: Use `?:` operator, it is supported in `{{}}`

Comment: What's your controller property? {{ property === "something" ? 1 : 0 }}

Answer (score 1):

#### Angular supports [expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

you can use a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-angular-templates-angularjs) inside expressions

```
<span> {{ property >= 1 ? 1 : 0 }} </span>
```

#### Alternatively, or you can use a filter

```
app.filter("myFilter",function){
   return function(number){
     return number >=1 ? 1 : 0;
   }
})
```

#### and use it like so:

```
<span> {{ property | myFilter }} </span>
```