# Is there a way to conditionally add filter inline?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
{{!filterNameVar ? valueVar : valueVar | filterNameVar}}
```

I need it for my dataGrid, if I get a filterName from dataGrid settings for a column I should apply it. I know I can do this in controller, but so far trying to find a way do it inline in a template.

Comment: Depends on which version of AngularJS you are using.

Comment: @Sameer Shemna Well I can switch to any recent stable release, the project I'm working on is still in a development stage.

Comment: Check this, a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-templates

Comment: @Sameer Shemna I've checked that out and tried, so far it seems like it works with strings {{ expres ? 'str1' : 'str2' }} but doesn't with expressions {{expres ? expres1  : expres2 }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround**

It seems you can't add a filter from a variable in an expression like this:

```
{{'20141212'|filterNameVariable}}
```

My workaround:

```
{{'20141212'|proxyFilter:filterNameVariable}}
```

Filter proxy code:

```
app.filter(
    "proxyFilter",
    function($filter) {
        return function(value, filterName) {
            if (filterName=='myFilter1') {
                return $filter("myFilter1")(value);
            } else if (filterName=='myFilter2') {
                return $filter("myFilter2")(value);
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        };
    });
```