# ng-class not responding to change in model in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having searched extensively, got some help from [A ternary in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-templates) and getting partially functional results, I'm 99% sure I'm doing it 99% right, but...obviously not completely, so I'm here.

The basic HTML structure:

```
<ul>
    <li class="week-row" ng-repeat="week in weeks" id="{{$index}}">
        <ul class="tiles" ng-class="{ 'expanded': week.isOpen, 'hidden': !week.isOpen }">
            <li class="day-tile"
                ng-class="{'active': (activeDay == $parent.$index + '-' + $index) }" 
                id="{{$parent.$index + '-' + $index}}" 
                ng-repeat="day in week.days" 
                ng-click="fn2({ week: $parent.$index, day: $index })">

               <!-- moved ng-class to here, and it works? -->
               <div>some stuff in here</div> 

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

The stuff in the controller that sits above it:

```
$scope.activeDay = null;

$scope.fn1 = function() { $scope.activeDay = '0-0'; }; // this works, and sets the first one active

$scope.fn2 = function(data) { $scope.activeDay = data.week + '-' + data.day; }; // this sets the first one not active, but none of the others go active
```

I'm trying to set one of the nested list items to be active, based on its indexes in the nested arrays by using the `$parent.$index` and `$index` as a string, joined by '-'.

What's throwing me off is that console.logging `$scope.activeDay`, `data.week + '-' + data.day`, and both `==` and `===` comparisons come out exactly as I would expect, `(the same strings, true, true)` and it works on initial load when I set activeDay to '0-0', so I'm clearly missing something in my binding or...?

After finding this: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot - I tried setting it up as an object so I couldn't get into some weird isolate scope nonsense:  `$scope.tiles = { activeDay: null };` and then setting that property from my functions, to no avail.

Why does setting it initially work, while changing it later does not? Is this improper binding of classes or...?

I also tried it with

`class="day-tile {{activeDay == $parent.$index + '-' + $index ? 'active' : ''}}"`

and that works initially, but breaks afterwards...

Your help is much appreciated!

### **UPDATE:**

After moving `ng-class="{'active': (activeDay == $parent.$index + '-' + $index) }"` onto the div inside the `ng-repeat`ed `.day-tile` li, it works fine.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr?

Comment: And somehow by copy/pasting my updated code into plunkr, it works there...so clearly I'm having some different issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the info you provided I have this working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8849/).

I removed the classes you were hard coding to true and stuck them in `class=""`.  The classes you were evaluating expressions for i put in `ng-class=""`.

I attached your functions to `$scope` so `ng-click` could find them.  So $scope.fn2 rather than var fn2.

Without knowing more details, I would say this should fix your problem.

**Code Changes:**

controller:

```
$scope.activeDay = null;

$scope.fn1 = function() { $scope.activeDay = '0-0'; };

$scope.fn2 = function(data) { $scope.activeDay = data.week + '-' + data.day; };
```

partial:

```
    <ul class="tiles" ng-class="{'expanded' : week.isOpen, 'hidden' : !week.isOpen}">
        <li class="day-title"
            ng-class="{'active': (activeDay == $parent.$index + '-' + $index)}" 
            id="{{$parent.$index + '-' + $index}}" 
            ng-repeat="day in week.days" 
            ng-click="fn2({ week: $parent.$index, day: $index })">
            //put expression here so you can see the list item
            {{week.day}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I get home in a bit. I did have fn1, fn2 on $scope, I just wrote those out in a rush, but this looks probably better than what I was doing. Thank you.

Comment: So, for some reason setting the ng-class on the ng-repeated li was failing? I have a div inside that li which I put the ng-class on, and it works fine.

Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: The ngClass is failing in the fiddle or in your code? If it's yours can you make a fiddle?

Comment: It's failing in mine, when I started making a plunkr, it worked fine with what I copy/pasted :/

Comment: Okay sorry I'm having trouble understanding? So it works well in your plunkr but not the actually code?

Comment: Yes. Trust me, you're as confused as I am. Why it would work fine outside the system I'm working in, or by moving the ng-class from the li, to it's child div makes no sense to me.