# Angular logic for repeater

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple repeater setup like so

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="location in data.posts">
  {{location.title}}
</ion-item>
```

And of course for every array I get a title inside an ion-item. Now for the tricky stuff.

`data` is coming from some `JSON` I'm pulling in. I want to access something deeper into the array but I don't know how to get it. In javascript I would access it as

```
location['custom_fields']['coupon_relationships']
```

Which `coupon_relationships` is another array for any amount of items. I merely want to be able to count the amount of items in there and print out the integer. Then I want to do logic so that the word *coupons* follows unless there is only 1 at which point I want the word to be *coupon*. I know I can do this all via javascript but I'm trying to learn the features of AngularJS. Is all this possible via Angular html?

Comment: it would help if you could post a small snippet of the json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell if this is exactly what you're interested in from your question, but you might try something like:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="location in data.posts">
  {{location.title}} -
  {{location.custom_fields.coupon_relationships.length}}
  {{location.custom_fields.coupon_relationships.length != 1 ? 'Coupons' : 'Coupon'}}
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

John's answer would be best for angular 1.1.5+ ([that's when they added the ternary operator in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-templates))

If you are running an old version you could do something like this:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="PollCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="poll in polls">
            <a href="#">
            {{poll.custom_fields.coupon_relationships.length}}
            Coupon<span ng-if="poll.custom_fields.coupon_relationships.length != 1">s</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
function PollCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.polls = [
        {
            custom_fields:
                {
                  coupon_relationships:
                     [
                       'one here', 'another','fffff','ffffff'
                     ]
                }
        }
     ]
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPNEYd)