# How to catch the toggle event of angular bootstrapUI accordion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working on the angular bootstrapUI accordion, I need to catch the toggle event for each section, for example, in each header of section, I have a arrow, when it is open the arrow-down will show,and other arrows in other sections will show arrow-right.something like this:

```
<accordion-group  is-open="true"  ng-repeat="destination in mileage.destionations">
            <accordion-heading>
                <span ng-class="{'fa-chevron-down': openEvent, 'fa-chevron-right': !openEvent">Toggle Me</span>
            </accordion-heading>
               <div class='accordion-section'>
                    Main content here
                </div>
        </accordion-group>
```

As you see,How can I toggle the class fa-chevron-down and fa-chevron-right for each section in the accordion-group?

Comment: I'm not sure about hte specifics of the accordion group `openEvent` but you're probably looking for an ng-class ternary example - `<span ng-class="openEvent ? 'fa-chevron-down' : 'fa-chevron-up'">` - src: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-templates

Comment: Thanks for you help. I know how ng-class works, the issue is I need to catch this event to tell the accordion to show different arrow picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really close...

change your `is-open` to a property name, and not a value. Else yours looks like `is-open` is always open (`true`).

So like this:

```
<accordion-group  is-open="isOpen"  ng-repeat="destination in mileage.destionations">
     <accordion-heading>
          <span ng-class="{'fa-chevron-down': isOpen, 'fa-chevron-right': !isOpen">Toggle Me</span>
      </accordion-heading>
      <div class='accordion-section'>
           Main content here
      </div>
 </accordion-group>
```

Now, when open `isOpen` will be set to `true`. When closed, it will be set to `false` and the icon toggle will work.

`isOpen` can be anything you like. Its just a `$scope` property that will be created and set. So you could use `is-open="iAmOpenNow"` and use `iAmOpen` in your `ng-class` :)

Comment: Thanks! How stupid I am!, I just moved from JQ, still thinking JQ way, haha.

Comment: to be fair, their documents for the accordion is really lacking.  It took me a few minutes to understand the purpose of `is-open` in that it's really an `ng-model` type attribute.  They could have really named it something better.