# Conditionally insert variable inside Angular brackets?

Tags: angularjs, templates, conditional-statements

Is it possible to do something like that in Angular?
Insert variable inside angular brackets on condition.

```
<div>{{ tElement.attr('multiple') ? $item.name : $item }}</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A ternary in templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008580/a-ternary-in-templates)

Comment: not as attribute, not inside quotes.