# mouseover event Angular JS access attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following directive

```
courseApp.directive("courseoverview", function() { 
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.switched = false;
        //hover handler
        scope.hoverItem = function(hovered){
        if (hovered) {
            //element.addClass('hover');
            $('#course-'+ scope.$index  +' figure').addClass('tint');
            //console.log(scope.$index);
        }
        else
            //element.removeClass('hover');
            $('#course-'+ scope.$index  +' figure').removeClass('tint');
        };
    }  
    return {    
      restrict : 'A',    
      replace: true,   
      transclude: true,    
      templateUrl: "views/course-overview.html",
      link: link
   }});
```

The directive is called with the following code

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in social" class="social-{{item.name}}" 
                ng-mouseover="hoverItem(true);"
                ng-mouseout="hoverItem(false);"
                current-social="{{item.name}}">
```

The hover function works great but i need access to this attribute in the directive, well i need the value of it.

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

First, your directive is named 'courseoverview' but I don't see that attribute anywhere in the markup you provided.

To address your question, you say *I need access to this attribute in the directive*. But I think you have the attributes in the link function - see the `attrs` parameter. Those are the attributes on the element that fired your directive.

```
 function link(scope, element, attrs) { ... }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11913918/48082) for more.