# How to resolve an attribute in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a directive and I'd like to have an attribute that can accept an expression, template url or string.  Is there an angular method I can use that will resolve such a parameter?  I mean where I can do....

```
<directive dialog="path/to/template.htm"></dialog>
```

or

```
<directive dialog="Are you sure you want to do that?" type="confirm"></dialog>
```

And in my directive code all I need to do is something like...

```
directive('dialog', function ($http) {
    return {
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            var dialogContent = angular.resolveExpression(attrs.dialog);
        }
    }
}).
```

The idea being that if `template.htm` contained expressions within it or directives that they would all be parsed correctly.

Comment: +1 I would love to know if that's possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913841/accessing-attributes-from-an-angularjs-directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do it is to use the `&` scope option...

```
directive('slideToggle', function () {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                on: '&',
                off: '&',
                bindto: '='
            },
            template: '<input type="checkbox" name=""/>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $(element).iButton({
                    labelOn: attrs.onlabel,
                    labelOff: attrs.offlabel,
                    enableDrag: (attrs.draggable == "false") ? false : true,
                    change: function () {
                        if (scope.bindto) {
                            scope.bindto = false;
                            scope.on();
                        } else {
                            scope.bindto = true;
                            scope.off();
                        }
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

Then in my HTML:

```
<slide-toggle onLabel="Active" offLabel="Inactive" bindTo="workstation.active" off="makeInactive()" on="makeActive()"></slide-toggle>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`attribute $observe`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#attributes) to achieve it, you would even get updates when attribute gets changed:

```js
app.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      attr.$observe('dialog', function(value) {
        // this function will run everytime the attribute evaluate to
        // a different value, and "value" will be the already interpolated
        // string.
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here is a working [Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140?p=preview).