# directive link attrs don't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

in html i call my directive with: `<div godata-pagination count="{{pagination.count}}" size="{{pagination.size}}" page="{{pagination.page}}"></div>`

then my directive looks inside:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log('attrs: ' + attrs.size);
    scope.pagCount = attrs.count;
    scope.pagPage = attrs.page;
}
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        count: '@',
        size: '@',
        page: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/godata/pagination.html',
    link: link
};
```

In the partial (partials/godata/pagination.html) i can access these variables (count, size and page). For 100% in partial i access originaly these three variables, no other in this scope.

But i will do something with these variables in function link.
If i try to access these variables in function link through attrs, they are empty :(

What is wrong and/or what can i do?

UPDATE:

[image: console log output]

And with `scope: false` scope variable is undefined.

And why brings the line `attrs.$observe('page', function(val) { console.log('$observe: ' + val); });` in function link two output ...one with and one without value?

UPDATE again:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log('scope: ' + scope.size);
    console.log('scope: ' + scope);
    console.log('attrs: ' + attrs.size);
    console.log('attrs: ' + attrs);
    attrs.$observe('size', function(size) {
        console.log('$observe: ' + size);
        if(size) {
            scope.pagSize = size;
        }
    });
    console.log('after observe; pagSize: ' + scope.pagSize);
}
```

...bring me:

[image: console log output]

But `scope.pagSize` has a value in browser.

How can i work with these attributes in my directive, if i can't access them?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913841/accessing-attributes-from-an-angularjs-directive

Comment: Try to console log the all attr object and see what's inside.

Comment: there is an empty Object `scope: [object Object]` and `attrs: [object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

They are bound to the scope of the directive.

You can access them with `scope.page`, `scope.count` for example.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hristo Enev Answered : when you have isolated scope it is better to access
attrs with  `scope.page` or `scope.count`

but if you insist to do that with attribute,

**this is the way:**

`attrs.$observe('page', function(val) { console.log(val) })`

results in the value of page attribute.

Inside the linking function, you should use $observe()  to get interpolated value.